# Selenium Web Driver & Java. Element is not clickable at point (x, y). Other element would receive the click

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I used explicit waits and I have the warning:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
>   Element is not clickable at point (36, 72). Other element would receive 
>   the click: ...
>   Command duration or timeout: 393 milliseconds

If I use `Thread.sleep(2000)` I don't receive any warnings.

```
@Test(dataProvider = "menuData")
public void Main(String btnMenu, String TitleResultPage, String Text) throws InterruptedException {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    driver.findElement(By.id("navigationPageButton")).click();

    try {
       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector(btnMenu)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Oh");
    }
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(btnMenu)).click();
    Assert.assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(TitleResultPage)).getText(), Text);
}
```

Comment: Are you using Chrome version 61+?

Comment: @demouser123 i am using Firefox 47.0.1 and seleniumWebDriver 2.51.0

Comment: @Maria On which line are you getting the error? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB In line: driver.findElement(By.id("navigationPageButton")).click();

Comment: That error means, there's another element overlaying the target element (fixed/absolute positioned overlay) or the z-index is too low. This might be caused by hover effects using transitions (slower than the minimum timeout, in this case 393ms). you should wait for `#navigationPageButton` to become visible (or clickable using `elementToBeClickable()` for that element too) or check whether all preconditions are met so that the button is clickable.

Comment: The issue can come if you are using Ext-JS or similar to make beautiful UI. I had similar issues and it was solved by sending <Space> key on the element to click on it.

Answer (score 211):

### WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point (x, y)

This is a typical [org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriverException.html) which extends *java.lang.RuntimeException*.

The fields of this exception are :

- [BASE_SUPPORT_URL](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriverException.html#BASE_SUPPORT_URL) : `protected static final java.lang.String BASE_SUPPORT_URL`
- [DRIVER_INFO](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriverException.html#DRIVER_INFO) : `public static final java.lang.String DRIVER_INFO`
- [SESSION_ID](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriverException.html#SESSION_ID) : `public static final java.lang.String SESSION_ID`

---

About your individual usecase, the error tells it all :

```
WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point (x, y). Other element would receive the click
```

It is clear from your code block that you have defined the `wait` as `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);` but you are calling the `click()` method on the element before  the `ExplicitWait` comes into play as in `until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable)`.

### Solution

The error `Element is not clickable at point (x, y)` can arise from different factors. You can address them by either of the following procedures:

**1. Element not getting clicked due to JavaScript or AJAX calls present**

Try to use `Actions` Class:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("navigationPageButton"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();
```

**2. Element not getting clicked as it is not within [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)**

Try to use **`JavascriptExecutor`** to bring the element within the Viewport:

```
WebElement myelement = driver.findElement(By.id("navigationPageButton"));
JavascriptExecutor jse2 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse2.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", myelement);
```

**3. The page is getting refreshed before the element gets clickable.**

In this case induce *ExplicitWait* i.e **WebDriverWait** as mentioned in point 4.

**4. Element is present in the DOM but not clickable.**

In this case induce *ExplicitWait* with  `ExpectedConditions` set to `elementToBeClickable` for the element to be clickable:

```
WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("navigationPageButton")));
```

**5. Element is present but having temporary Overlay.**

In this case, induce **`ExplicitWait`** with  **`ExpectedConditions`** set to **`invisibilityOfElementLocated`** for the Overlay to be invisible.

```
WebDriverWait wait3 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait3.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("ele_to_inv")));
```

**6. Element is present but having permanent Overlay.**

Use `JavascriptExecutor` to send the click directly on the element.

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("element_xpath"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ele);
```

Comment: To #6/#2 above: The .ExecuteScript method is now accessible from the web driver itself rather than the JavascriptExecutor.
Thanks for the well written answer!

Comment: You have covered many possibilities in which only 5 and 6 are correct way to handle the mentioned error. The first four throws different error for which the solution you gave won't work. For an example point number 3 is actually a stale element problem that wouldn't work even though how long you wait with elementToBeClickble method. That has to be handled differently.

Comment: 6 is not really correct it;s a hack to work around the issue, 5 would be correct if the correct expected condition was being used.  4 looks like the only correct answer.

Comment: An important thing to note is, when we're emulating user's actions, it may be very undesirable to use javascript to click on element that can't be clicked at all (#6). The end user would never do that, they would just either scroll to the element to bring it into viewport or dismiss any overlay (if allowed by the page) to interact with it.

Answer (score 21):

In case you need to use it with Javascript

We can use arguments[0].click() to simulate click operation.

```
var element = element(by.linkText('webdriverjs'));
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click()",element);
```

Comment: Works! I cannot imagine way it works, but otherwise it clicks on overlay layer (waiting of overlay closing by 'invisibilityOfElementLocated' takes  about 30sec.).

Comment: Can you please write the full explanation since I write in java and it is not familiar war, can you please provide full flow?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this error while trying to click some element (or its overlay, I didn't care), and the other answers didn't work for me.  I fixed it by using the `elementFromPoint` DOM API to find the element that Selenium wanted me to click on instead:

```
element_i_care_about = something()
loc = element_i_care_about.location
element_to_click = driver.execute_script(
    "return document.elementFromPoint(arguments[0], arguments[1]);",
    loc['x'],
    loc['y'])
element_to_click.click()
```

I've also had situations where an element was *moving*, for example because an element above it on the page was doing an animated expand or collapse.  In that case, this Expected Condition class helped.  You give it the *elements that are animated*, not the ones you want to click.  This version only works for jQuery animations.

```
class elements_not_to_be_animated(object):
    def __init__(self, locator):
        self.locator = locator

    def __call__(self, driver):
        try:
            elements = EC._find_elements(driver, self.locator)
            # :animated is an artificial jQuery selector for things that are
            # currently animated by jQuery.
            return driver.execute_script(
                'return !jQuery(arguments[0]).filter(":animated").length;',
                elements)
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            return False
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
WebElement navigationPageButton = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
 .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("navigationPageButton")));
navigationPageButton.click();
```

Comment: It is not help me.

Comment: Yes:
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point (36, 72). Other element would receive the click: <div tabindex="0" class="waiter-ui-lock"></div>
Command duration or timeout: 70 milliseconds

Comment: try the following
`WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("navigationPageButton"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element).click().perform();`

Comment: It is not help too. I have two Exception and one AssertionError and next some error "Element is not clickable at point "

Comment: Are you sure page is not refreshing at the time you are trying to click?

Comment: A pop-up menu appears on the page but the page itself is not updated

Comment: Maybe you now operate on pop-up window instead?

Comment: If i using Thread.Sleep then all work. But i using Wait all fail.

Comment: `presenceOfElementLocated()` is not enough, the element has been located. The error message would be different if the element cannot be located. The error says the element is not visible or something overlays that element.

Comment: I have the same problem, after a modal dialog is opened, I'm not able to click element inside the dialog. Have already tried all suggestions from this thread, nothing worked. I can identify the overlaying frame, but cannot switch to the frame, getting NoSuchFrameException.

Comment: @pburgr How do you switch to the frame?

Comment: with this I'm getting NoSuchFrameException: WebElement languageModal = driver.findElement(By.id("languageModal"));
   driver.switchTo().frame(languageModal);
but    WebElement languageModal = driver.findElement(By.id("languageModal"));
   languageModal.click(); is OK, no exception at all.

Comment: @pburgr Are you able to locate frame through id in browser console?

Answer (score 2):

Scrolling the page to the near by point mentioned in the exception did the trick for me. Below is code snippet:

```
$wd_host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub';
$capabilities =
    [
        \WebDriverCapabilityType::BROWSER_NAME => 'chrome',
        \WebDriverCapabilityType::PROXY => [
            'proxyType' => 'manual',
            'httpProxy' => PROXY_DOMAIN.':'.PROXY_PORT,
            'sslProxy' => PROXY_DOMAIN.':'.PROXY_PORT,
            'noProxy' =>  PROXY_EXCEPTION // to run locally
        ],
    ];
$webDriver = \RemoteWebDriver::create($wd_host, $capabilities, 250000, 250000);
...........
...........
// Wait for 3 seconds
$webDriver->wait(3);
// Scrolls the page vertically by 70 pixels 
$webDriver->executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, 70);");
```

**NOTE:** I use [Facebook php webdriver](https://gist.github.com/sudheeshms/8ce553d7581e4ad7c6f76a8b7fed28ab)

Answer (score 1):

If element is not clickable and overlay issue is ocuring we use **arguments[0].click().**

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='input-group-btn']/input"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ele);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to override the click functionality:

```
public void _click(WebElement element){
    boolean flag = false;
    while(true) {
        try{
            element.click();
            flag=true;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            flag = false;
        }
        if(flag)
        {
            try{
                element.click();
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                System.out.printf("Element: " +element+ " has beed clicked, Selenium exception triggered: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C#, I had problem with checking `RadioButton`, 
and this worked for me:

```
driver.ExecuteJavaScript("arguments[0].checked=true", radio);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can try with below code

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
```

**Pass other element would receive the click**:`<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>`

```
    boolean invisiable = wait.until(ExpectedConditions
            .invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='navbar-brand']")));
```

**Pass clickable button id as shown below**

```
    if (invisiable) {
        WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='button']");
        ele.click();
    }
```