# Selenium Python: How to click a disabled element?

Tags: python, selenium

Facing the following error when using

```
driver.find_element_by_id(element_id).click()
```

to click a disabled element.

> **Error:**
> ... is not clickable at point (1585, 222). Other element would receive the click:

Comment: Can  u post complete stack trace

Comment: Sorry, cannot share raw traceback for security reasons. What else may help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Web Driver & Java. Element is not clickable at point (36, 72). Other element would receive the click:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el)

Comment: If you "can't share the traceback," then you need a [mcve]. Actually, you need one anyway.

Comment: Will try to screen info:                                                     WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <input type="radio" autocomplete="off" value="chocolate" data-bind="
                                                checked: chocolate,
                                                disable: isEmpty() || !chocolate(),
                                                attr: {
                                                    'id': 'chocolate' + $index() + 'chocolate',

Comment: 'name': 'chocolate' + $index() }" name="chocolate" id="chocolate"> is not clickable at point (1585, 222). Other element would receive the click: <span class="chocolate" data-bind="css: { 'chocolatee': chocolate() === 'chocolate' &amp;&amp; chocolate(),
                                                                'fa-times-circle': chocolate() !== 'chocolate' &amp;&amp; chocolate(),
                                                                'i-chocolate-spacer': !chocolate() }"></span>

Comment: Please edit your question and put all relevant info inside the question instead of in comments so it's more easily found.

Comment: The element isn't disabled. Another element would receive the click so some other element is on top of the element you are trying to click. This could be something like a dialog or a sidebar or it could be that the page was still loading, resizing content when you tried to click. We can't tell because you haven't provided any details.

Comment: Thanks @JeffC ! there was a tiny icon over the label I was trying to click! Finally worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element isn't disabled. Another element would receive the click so some other element is on top of the element you are trying to click. This could be something like a dialog or a sidebar or it could be that the page was still loading, resizing content when you tried to click. We can't tell because you haven't provided any details. – **JeffC 27 mins ago**

https://stackoverflow.com/users/2386774/jeffc

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', driver.find_element_by_id(element_id))
```