# Geb test intermittent failure firefox - org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point

Tags: selenium, groovy, spock, geb

I am getting following error intermittently at a component click in my geb UI tests on Firefox 45.0.1, Selenium 2.53.1 and following Jars:

geb-spock-1.1.1.jar

geb-core-1.1.1.jar

geb-ast-1.1.1.jar

geb-waiting-1.1.1.jar

geb-implicit-assertions-1.1.1.jar

geb-exceptions-1.1.1.jar

geb-test-common-1.1.1.jar

spock-spring-1.0-groovy-2.4.jar

spock-core-1.0-groovy-2.4.jar

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point (499.95001220703125, 375.6000061035156). Other element would receive the click:

The tests fail intermittently. Adding a sleep of 200 ms before component click viz. sleep(200) does help but I do not want to use sleep() with such fix time values for the sake of good practice.

[waitFor()](http://gebish.org/manual/1.0/api/geb/Page.html#waitFor(java.util.Map,%20%20java.lang.String,%20Closure%3CT%3E)) does not help either:

```
myButton(wait:true) {$('#myBtn')}
waitFor { myButton.isDisplayed() }
myButton.click()
```

Launching tests in full screen also does not make things any better:

```
def setupSpec() {
        getDriver().manage().window().maximize()
    }
```

Comment: Provide reproducible case / sample code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Web Driver & Java. Element is not clickable at point (36, 72). Other element would receive the click:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el)

Answer (score 0):

Its likely that the element is `displayed` before it is `clickable` I have seen this behaviour with clickable elements that animate. E.G.

- Page loads
- button is displayed
- button begins animating
- button animation finishes
- Button is clickable

Given this is intermittent I suspect the problem is related. It might not be animation related but a simple race condition.

you could add a method to your pageObject or even better create a custom navigator that waits for the element to be clickable:

```
def waitForAndClick(Navigator element, Integer timeoutSeconds) {
    def timeStart = new Date().getTime()
    while ( timeStart <= timeStart + timeoutSeconds ) {
        try { 
            element.click()
        }
        catch (WebDriverException ex) {
             pass
        }
        break
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.