# How to click on a button present in ion-buttons and having style using selenium

Tags: cordova, selenium

I am trying to click on the button using selenium on my ionic cordova application. I tried click(), javascript, tap but nothing work.

Can anyone please take a look and suggest. I have attached the screenshot.[image]

Error coming when tried with span.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to click on span or div inside?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. I am able to get the text "Accept" but it's not clickable.

Comment: So no error but the click doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, no error is coming.

Comment: Any suggestions to click on the Accept button here?

Comment: Hard to say without looking at application

Answer (score 1):

As you have highlighted it may be a bit difficult to click on the `<button>` tag. Hence you can try to click on the inner `<span>` tag as follows:

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn-done disable-hover bar-button bar-button-md bar-button-default bar-button-default-md']/span[@class='button-inner']"));
ele.click();
```

### Update:

Now as you are seeing a `WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point (--, --)`. It can happen for a number of reasons as discussed in this [**`Discussion`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el). So we will use the `JavascriptExecutor` click as follows:

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn-done disable-hover bar-button bar-button-md bar-button-default bar-button-default-md']/span[@class='button-inner']"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ele);
```

Comment: Yes tried with span and with the locator you shared but it's not working. Is that because of an ionic button? Any resolution for that.

Comment: Can you update the question with the exact error stack trace?

Comment: Hey Debanjan, I have updated the error when trying to click on the span locator in the problem.

Comment: @Alex Check my updated Answer and let me know the status.

Comment: No, I am not able to click through javascriptExecutor. Tried with both css and xpath. Looks like this is a problem of ion-card or ion-buttons (see the dom of html in the screenshot of the problem). Even with javascriptExcecutor no error is coming and I am able to get the text.

Comment: Please bump up `Selenium` to v3.5.0, `chromedriver` to 2.31 and `Chrome` to 60.x you will be through.