# Selenium webdriver C# :Locating and entering values in a input text element inside a label works on local but not on TeamCity

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have label on my webpage. When i click on the Label, input text field appears. Moving away from this element, will become a label again. I am trying to click the label, clear the text in the input text element and enter text in the input field.

html before click on the label:

```
    <tbody _ngcontent-c5="">
<!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object]" }-->
<tr _ngcontent-c5="">
<td _ngcontent-c5="" class="check-box" style="border-right:#dcdcdc;">
<input _ngcontent-c5="" name="isSelected" type="checkbox" id="parameter[0].isSelected" data-index="0"></td>
<td _ngcontent-c5="" class="max-width non-editable-cell">All Countries</td>
<td _ngcontent-c5="" class="max-width non-editable-cell">All Store Affluences</td>
<td _ngcontent-c5="" class="med-width non-editable-cell">
<!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-if": "true" }-->
<div _ngcontent-c5="" id="parameter[0].planogramNameLabel">Master Range</div>
<!--bindings={}-->
</td>
```

html after clicking on the label:

```
<tbody _ngcontent-c5=""> <!--bindings={ "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object]"
}--><tr _ngcontent-c5="">
<td _ngcontent-c5="" class="check-box" style="border-right:#dcdcdc;">
<input _ngcontent-c5="" name="isSelected" type="checkbox" id="parameter[0].isSelected" data-index="0"></td>
<td _ngcontent-c5="" class="max-width non-editable-cell">All Countries</td>
<td _ngcontent-c5="" class="max-width non-editable-cell">All Store Affluences</td>
<td _ngcontent-c5="" class="med-width non-editable-cell">
<!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"}-->
<!--bindings={ "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"}-->
<input _ngcontent-c5="" class="planogram-parameter-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" name="planogramName" type="text" ng-reflect-name="planogramName" ng-reflect-model="Master Range" id="parameter[0].planogramName" data-index="0">
</td>
```

The label is a dynamic element.

Please find my code:

```
IWebElement planogramNameLabelelement = Driver.FindElement(By.Id(Constants.Ids["PLANOGRAM_LABEL"]));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(planogramNameLabelelement));
Actions action = new Actions(Driver);
action.MoveToElement(planogramNameLabelelement).Click().Build().Perform();

IWebElement planogramNameelement = Driver.FindElement(By.Id(Constants.Ids["PLANOGRAM_NAME"]));
planogramNameelement.Clear();   
planogramNameelement.SendKeys(planogramname);
```

This code runs perfectly fine in my local. When i try to run these tests on TeamCity. Its unable to locate planogramNameElement.

Please find the error below:

> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"parameter[0].planogramName"}
>     (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64)
>
> at penQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
>
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
>
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
>
> at Automation_Dunnhumby_Framework.Steps.SpaceRecsRequestSteps.GivenIEnterShelfdepthShelfHeightTotalmodsModulelengthShelvespermoduleInTheField(String planogramname, String shelfdepth, String shelfheight, String totalmods, String modulelength, String shelvespermodule) in D:\BuildAgent\work\7f925fcfe8130d53\Automation_Dunnhumby_Framework\Automation_Dunnhumby_Framework\Steps\SpaceRecsRequestSteps.cs:line 53
>
> at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration)
>
> at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStepMatch(BindingMatch match, Object[] arguments)
>
> at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(IContextManager contextManager, StepInstance stepInstance)
>
> at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnAfterLastStep()

Comment: Is it possible the machine that runs the tests from TeamCity is slower than your local PC?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try adding a wait before locating an element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of observations from the `HTML` you provided:

1. The **`AUT (Application Under Test)`** uses **`Javascript`**/**`Ajax Calls`** which is clear from the attributes e.g. **`id="parameter[0].isSelected"`**
2. Once you `click the label` then the `input text field appears`. So there is a delta time difference between the `click()` and rendering of the `input text field` which is not taken into consideration in your script as in your code block just after **`Perform()`** you are trying to **`Clear()`** the `input text field` as follows:

   ```
   action.MoveToElement(planogramNameLabelelement).Click().Build().Perform();
   IWebElement planogramNameelement = Driver.FindElement(By.Id(Constants.Ids["PLANOGRAM_NAME"]));
   planogramNameelement.Clear();
   ```

### Solution:

A proper solution to your issue would be to induce **`ExplicitWait`** i.e. **`WebDriverWait`** with **`ExpectedConditions`** as **`ElementToBeClickable`** for the `input text field` to be `clickable` as follows:

```
action.MoveToElement(planogramNameLabelelement).Click().Build().Perform();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement planogramNameelement = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id(Constants.Ids["PLANOGRAM_NAME"]));
planogramNameelement.Clear();
```

Comment: I added explicit wait as mentioned in your suggestion above. But now i am getting a different error. It waits till the explicit wait and then times out.  Error: System.InvalidOperationException : unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (886, 695).Error caught : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:59783/session/a7f779c75cbbab11b52b4710628d2e84/element timed out after 60 seconds.

Comment: @user8734797 Great, so we have solved your actual question by addressing `NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element` For the new exception please refer this [Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el/44916498#44916498). Can you Accept the Answer please.