# Selenium C# Automation is working in some Machine and not working in some machine

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

Recently,I created some automation script in C# to perform auto UI testing rather than manual.So It's working good in my machine but if I use the same script in my friend's machine it says."**Element is not clickable at this point**" but same thing is working in my machine without any exception.As I see it looks like the button which is trying to click is located on the bottom of the page and we need to scroll down to click the button.In my Machine,the scroll down action is done automatically without any more script and  is not getting any exception but in my friend's Machine, I don't see any scroll down action is performing so it's not working and getting error as I mentioned above. The sample script is as below.[image: Snapshot of this error is]

```
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("profile.name")).SendKeys("name");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("profile.ProviderIsAgreed")).Click();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("btn_next")).Click();
```

Above two buttons are located on the bottom of page.
Please any idea what's happening.Any solution will be really appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Web Driver & Java. Element is not clickable at point (36, 72). Other element would receive the click:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el)

Comment: @DebanjanB it's little bit different error that you have mentioned right??

Comment: Check all the 6 usecases, one or the other will surely cater to the issue you are facing.

Comment: @DebanjanB I have uploaded screenshot of the error.What are the 6 use cases?

Comment: Check this [Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el/44916498#44916498) to overcome the error `Element is not clickable at point (x, y)`

Comment: Thank you so much @DebanjanB it was case 2 and I have solved the issue.So I need to execute these line of code before click a element in all pages right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156261/discussion-between-krishna-joshi-and-debanjanb).