# Using aria-label to locate and click an element with Python3 and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I want to click or more respectively, expand the "Any time" button. I've tried to locate the element by class_name and xpath. The problem is that the class and xpath are the same for all three 'options'. So, I would like to select and click or expand on that element by using the aria-label. I found a couple of suggestions, but it didn't work for me. Most importantly, I try to do that in python 3. I also tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(""" //div*[@aria-label='Any Time'] """).click()
```

but it doesn't work.

Could anyone please help me? Many thanks in advance!

```html
<div class="hdtb-mn-hd" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-label="Any country"><div class="mn-hd-txt">Any country</div><span class="mn-dwn-arw"></span></div>
<div class="hdtb-mn-hd" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-label="Any time"><div class="mn-hd-txt">Any time</div><span class="mn-dwn-arw"></span></div>
<div class="hdtb-mn-hd" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-label="All results"><div class="mn-hd-txt">All results</div><span class="mn-dwn-arw"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using the `aria-label` property you can try the following `xpath`:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@aria-label='Any time']/div[@class='mn-hd-txt' and text()='Any time']");
```

> OR

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@aria-label='Any time']/div[@class='mn-hd-txt'][text()='Any time']");
```

If using `aria-label` property is not a mandatory requirement you can use the following:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='hdtb-mn-hd']/div[@class='mn-hd-txt' and text()='Any time']");
```

> OR

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='hdtb-mn-hd']/div[@class='mn-hd-txt'][text()='Any time']");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, @DebanjanB! All of your suggestions work, however, I still can't click on it, or more respectively expand it.
I get the following error message:

`Message: unknown error: Element <div class="mn-hd-txt">...</div> is not clickable at point (306, 99). Other element would receive the click: <a class="q qs" href="/search?q=ISIS+OR+IS+OR+%22Islamic+State%22&amp;dcr=0&amp;source=lnms&amp;tbm=isch&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=0ahUKEwjYy56A4OrWAhWFDMAKHVG9BDAQ_AUICygC">...</a>`

Any ideas how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: For `Element is not clickable at point (x, y)` see this [**`Discussion / QA`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el/44916498#44916498)

Comment: For those trying to do the same for other things... Another example; `tags = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//textarea[@aria-label='tags']")` where 'tags' is aria-label="tags" (in the 'view source' of a page) in a 'textarea' element. You can swap 'textarea' with 'input' if it is an input field instead and so on.

Answer (score 33):

So, I was just wrestling with this for the last couple days, and it was proving to be a huge headache. The aria-label was basically the only reliable attribute, and the xpath solution was not working for me.

On a whim, I tried using:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[aria-label=XXXX]")
```

where XXXX was the aria labels that I was searching for in single quotes (e.g. "[aria-label='More']"). Worked like a charm.

All this to say, try using the css selector. It *just works.*

Comment: You may need to quote this, namely `find_element(s)_by_css_selector("element[property='foo']")`. Using a `div` for example: `...selector("div[aria-label='XXXX']")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { By } from "selenium-webdriver";    

await driver.findElements(By.css("svg[aria-label='Hello']"));
```