# SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string 'xpath' is not a valid XPath expression

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

when i am trying to find element using below xpath i'm getting syntax error,so what could be a reason, i'm following this question but it's not working for me

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58400631/12849200

My Xpath:

```
dp_month = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*/td[@aria-label='+month_label+']/div[contains(text(),'+ x_month +')]')
```

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*/td[@area-label=November 2025]/div[contains(text(),NOV)] because of the following error:
```

```
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*/td[@area-label=November 2025]/div[contains(text(),NOV)]' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the XPath in the error message, you will probably see what the issue is. Your text isn't surrounded by quotes as is required, e.g.

```
td[@area-label=November 2025]
```

should be

```
td[@area-label="November 2025"]
```

To fix this, you need to adjust your line of code to

```
dp_month = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*/td[@aria-label="'+month_label+'"]/div[contains(text(),"'+ x_month +'")]')
```