# How to do find aria-label using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

This is my code-->

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[aria-label='收回讚']")
```

It doesn't work, it creates an `None` type. Any help is appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

update:

my update code:

```
try:
     element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[aria-label='收回讚']")))
     #check if unlike path exisit
  

except:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[aria-label='讚']")))
    element.click()
    #if not find like path and click it
```

[image: this is a reference of the html]

Comment: Please add the html , find_elemnts should return empty list

Comment: @DebanjanB, it still doesn't work :( let me put more informations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[aria-label='收回讚']")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@aria-label='收回讚']")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed descroptions in:

- [Using aria-label to locate and click an element with Python3 and Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46669850/using-aria-label-to-locate-and-click-an-element-with-python3-and-selenium/46670342#46670342)

Comment: @Yu-ChuehWang There was a minor bug which I corrected. Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.