# Additional information unknown error?

Tags: c#, css, selenium

I have the following error:

> Additional information: unknown error: Element ... is not clickable at point (542, 786). Other element would receive the click:

Any suggestions?

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.ClassName("fa fa-refresh fa-3x fa-spin")));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("/html/body/div[4]/div/main/div/div/section/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/a")));
IWebElement viewAllWc = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[4]/div/main/div/div/section/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/a"));
viewAllWc.Click();
```

Comment: This error is thrown when a button is disabled or there is something covering the button making selenium unable to click the button. Watch the playback of your test and see if the button is visible when the click action is performed.

Comment: @JonahOberloh its a spinner which is enabled before doing something else

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el/44916498#44916498