# WebDriver Waits not working on FindElement

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, async-await

WebDriver is not waiting for elements to be enabled or displayed in my web application. The web application extensively uses AJAX/Javascript for loading a very large, dynamic application, specifically Bubble's web application editor (https://bubble.is). I am developing applications using bubble and want to use Selenium/WebDriver from within the Bubble editor.

When using implicit waits, explicit waits and fluent waits, attempts to click on an element always return the following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <div class="tab tabs-3">...</div> is not clickable at point (30, 185). Other element would receive the click: <div class="status-notification" style="display: block;">...</div>
```

This issue appears to be related to elements appearing in the DOM before they are fully loaded. The following Java code is what is being used here, compiled and run in Eclipse IDE on Java 9:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
        WebDriver chrome = bubbleLogin(false); // login to application via static page. this step works
        WebDriver driver = chrome;
    //  load app 
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS);


        driver.get("https://bubble.is/page?type=page&name=index&id=test123456code&tab=tabs-1");
        switchToWindowWithTitle("test123456", driver);

//      EXPLICIT WAIT: wait for "elementToBeClickable" to be true - element must be displayed and enabled
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.tab.tabs-3")));
//      FLUENT WAIT: wait for element.IsEnabled to be true - element must be displayed and enabled
// instantiate an instance of this class to run the wait function I wrote
        testng test = new testng(); 
        test.waitUntilElementExistsAndIsEnabled(driver,By.cssSelector("div.tab.tabs-3"));

//      only works via sleep... not implicit, explicit or fluent waits

//      Thread.sleep(10000);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.tab.tabs-3")).click();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("failed run");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

And the above FluentWait method:

```
private void waitUntilElementExistsAndIsEnabled(WebDriver driver, final By by) {
       new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .pollingEvery(DEFAULT_SLEEP_TIME_IN_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
          .until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
             public Boolean apply(WebDriver wd) {
                return wd.findElement(by).isEnabled(); 
             }
          });
    }
```

Here is a complete dump of the error message from Eclipse:
(Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)

```
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498537 (cb2f855cbc7b82e20387eaf9a43f6b99b6105061),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds

Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T16:15:26.402Z'

System info: host: 'Krystals-MacBook-Air.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:c33:4430:fcfd:933c%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.1', java.version: '9'

Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver

Capabilities [{mobileEmulationEnabled=false, hasTouchScreen=false, platform=MAC, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=MAC, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=, applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.32.498537 (cb2f855cbc7b82e20387eaf9a43f6b99b6105061), userDataDir=/var/folders/gr/lggvp4hn09x2zqg6k561y4fr0000gn/T/.org.chromium.Chromium.haqAAG}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, unhandledPromptBehavior=, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=61.0.3163.100, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, locationContextEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]

Session ID: 0c9110334bb1b20a306363006f4bb868

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:82)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:45)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:586)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:279)
at             org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:83)
at testng.main(testng.java:497)
```

Comment: Did you read the exception message? What does it say?

Comment: For the error `Element is not clickable at point (x, y)` see this QA/Discussion  [Selenium Web Driver & Java. Element is not clickable at point (36, 72). Other element would receive the click:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el)

Comment: @DebanjanB Thanks for the response, I'll try to use the actions class to get the click working with explicit waits.

Comment: @JeffC What do you mean? The exception message `Element is not clickable`?

Answer (score -1):

i used

1. thread.sleep before i click the element and then
2. i will find the parent element before i click the main element

or

```
(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Reset")));
boolean Sort = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Reset")).isDisplayed();
if (Sort == true){
}else{
}
```

hope it will works

Comment: Thanks! I'd like to avoid any use of thread.sleep(X) if possible, as a dynamic wait that waits for certain conditions to be true would be much more efficient. The explicit wait looks similar to what I've been trying - I'll try to find the parent element first if using the Actions functions doesn't help this.