# Cannot click on visible text but isDisplayed=False

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am practicing Selenium-Webdriver and encounter the issue that the desirable element(text) is visible on web page, but I cannot click on it.

Trying to do check this element is displayed or not by command line "isDisplayed", and the console returns false result. I am a little bit confused that the text(please see the highlight on attached file) on web is visible but why cannot be clickable?

On this case, how can we perform some actions on it? could you please share your ideas and strategy to do.

Thank you so much.

Here is the web page:
http://www.lazada.com.ph/

[image: Screenshot of the Lazada webpage]

My code is

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driver_path);
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     driver.get("https://www.lazada.com.ph/");


     //Click on Men's Fashion
     WebElement loc = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-qa-locator='brands-by-category-cats-item']/div[@data-tab-id='2']"));
     Actions hover = new Actions(driver);
     hover.moveToElement(loc).click().build().perform();
```

Error log:

```
false

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: (-2114, -93.0999984741211) is out of bounds of viewport width (1366) and height (659)
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T16:15:26.402Z'
System info: host: 'Lorem', ip: '192.168.30.1', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_65'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{moz:profile=C:\Users\Lorem\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.y3xzzu5rD0i5, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0, pageLoad=300000, script=30000}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, moz:headless=false, platform=XP, specificationLevel=0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, acceptInsecureCerts=true, browserVersion=56.0.2, platformVersion=6.3, moz:processID=4724, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=XP}]
Session ID: 893e64ce-b53c-4bec-9f98-14832e4b7151
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:185)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:120)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:586)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.perform(RemoteWebDriver.java:652)
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions$BuiltAction.perform(Actions.java:638)
    at basic.Wait.main(Wait.java:41)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says it all as follows :

```
org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: (-2114, -93.0999984741211) is out of bounds of viewport width (1366) and height (659)
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T16:15:26.402Z'
```

The **`WebElement`** which you are trying to click is **`Not Visible`** as it is out of the [**`Viewport`**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp). As you have used **`Actions`** Class hence it shows **`MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException`**

You can consider the following code block to scroll the **`WebElement`** within the **`Viewport`** first then take help of `JavascriptExecutor` to click  as follows :

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("start-maximized");
    options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
    options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); 
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.lazada.com.ph/");
    //Click on Men's Fashion
    WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='c-category-tab  c-brands-by-category__tab']/span[@class='c-category-tab__icon c-category-tab__icon_category-fashion']"));
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elem);
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elem);
```

Comment: Thanks @DebanjanB, It works on both of Chrome and Firefor. I have just small question that the viewport which is relates to the screen-size. It normally describe how the UI looks like on Desktop, mobile, tablet view; but it is also have relationship to the visible of an element on a DEsktop view, could you please show me some article or knowledge regarding it? 

Moreover, using javascriptexecutor is also helpful as you helped me; but from the point of view of a tester,  is there any recommendation when using it ? 
Thanks.

Comment: This [**`Discussion/QA`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el/44916498#44916498) will clear a lot of your queries. Let me know if you have any question. Feel free to **`Upvote`** any Answers if they are useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you'r xpath giving more then one element .

try below code .

```
WebElement loc = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@data-qa-locator='brands-by-category-cats-item']/div[@data-tab-id='2'])[2]"));
     Actions hover = new Actions(driver);
     hover.moveToElement(loc).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: Thanks Ankur for helping me out. But it seems that this just work on Chrome, not in Firefox. :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your xpath return 3 elements. If you try the following code, you could notice this:

```
        //Click on Men's Fashion
        List<WebElement> loc = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@data-qa-locator='brands-by-category-cats-item']/div[@data-tab-id='2']"));
        System.out.println(loc.size());
        int i=1;
        for(WebElement we :loc)
        {
            System.out.println("innerText:" + we.getAttribute("innerText"));
            System.out.println("getLocation: " + we.getLocation());
            System.out.println("getText: " + we.getText());
            System.out.println("getSize: " + we.getSize());
            if(we.getText().contains("Men's Fashion"))
            {
                we.click();
            }

            System.out.println("------------ "+i+" -------------");
            i++;
        }
```

The output is:

```
3
innerText:Men's Fashion
getLocation: (-2210, 838)
getText: 
getSize: (141, 118)
------------ 1 -------------
innerText:Men's Fashion
getLocation: (178, 838)
getText: Men's Fashion
getSize: (141, 118)
------------ 2 -------------
innerText:Men's Fashion
getLocation: (2567, 838)
getText: 
getSize: (141, 118)
------------ 3 -------------
```

If you click the element with `getText=Men's Fashion` it works.

To be honest I don't know why the xpath return 3 elements. I hope someone give the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to reach to this element. couple more below.

```
//span[@data-id=4]
//span[@data-tracking-nav-header="Men's Fashion"]
```