# my cucumber feature step always stop running when occuring the time out & element not clickable issue

Tags: selenium, protractor, cucumber

My cucumber feature step always stops running when occurring the time out & element not clickable issue.

when running my automation script of couple feature file together, my cucumber feature step always stops running when met the issue mentioned above, this causes me can't generate the final status report. can anyone help with this issue? is that because my cucumber version is too old?

below is my package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
    "chai": "4.0.2",
    "chai-as-promised": "7.1.1",
    "cucumber": "^2.3.0",
    "cucumber-html-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "protractor": "5.1.1",
    "protractor-cucumber-framework": "^3.1.1",
    "q": "^1.5.0",
    "simple-oauth2": "^1.2.0",
    "cucumber-junit": "^1.7.0"
```

and below is the snapshot of my error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmdfJ.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Web Driver & Java. Element is not clickable at point (36, 72). Other element would receive the click:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el)

Comment: try having your scripts issue the webdriver commands to resize the browser to a standard size after you open it.  The most common cause of element not clickable errors is either the element is outside the viewport the user would see (so a user could never click it) or it is covered by another element (which would get the click).   Most often this is due to the browser opening up at a non-standard size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please set the ***ignoreUncaughtExceptions*** flag to true in your protractor configuration like mentioned below:

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: env.seleniumAddress,
    framework: 'custom',
    frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
    ignoreUncaughtExceptions: true,
}
```