# Cannot find element using href or text()

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Element:

```
<a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071NZZHF9" rel="nofollow noreferrer"> == $0
   "

    B071NZZHF9

   "
```

Tried:

```
WebElement element = dr.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='B071NZZHF9']"));
```

And tried:

```
WebElement element = dr.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B071NZZHF9']"));
```

But got an error: Unable to locate element and unable to click the element

Comment: Can you update the question with some more of the outerHTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this xpath and apply wait and try

```
//a[contains(text(), 'B071NZZHF9')]
```

Try this code with Explicit wait:

```
WebDriverWait waitForElement= new WebDriverWait (20,dr);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'B071NZZHF9')]")));
dr.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'B071NZZHF9')]")).click();
```

Comment: Please accept as asnwer on clicking right icon, so it help me and others:)

Answer (score 0):

As per the `HTML` you have shared to click on the `WebElement` you can use :

```
dr.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B071NZZHF9']")).click();
```

Comment: tried using this code. but it does not work as it throws some error saying not able to click the element, rather some other element will be clicked

Comment: Great !!! So we have now solved our main issue. To address the `not able to click the element, rather some other element will be clicked` issue follow the steps in this [**`QA/Discussion`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el/44916498#44916498). Please Accept the Answer.