# 'Element is not clickable at point (x, y) Other element would receive the click' after updating chrome browser

Tags: selenium, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

Getting following error after updating to latest Chrome Browser and latest Chrome Driver

```
Failed: unknown error: Element <button type="button" class="primary active">...</button> is not clickable at point (989, 603). Other element would receive the click: <div class="navItems">...</div>
(Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.94)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64)
```

Environment details :

> Chrome Browser version = 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)
>   chromedriver = 2.33.506120
>  platform = Windows NT 6.3.9600
>   x86_64
>  Node = 6.11.2
>  NPM = 3.10.10
>  Protractor =
>   5.1.2
>  webdriver-manager = 12.0.6

**Problem** : When I try to click a button which is at bottom of the screen but not visible on the screen then I am getting above error.

**Work around** : After using scroll into view of the element and then click like

```
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element.getWebElement());
element.click();
```

By using this workaround I am able to resolve the issue but I'll need to make changes in all script files.

> My scripts were working fine for 
> - chrome browser - 61.0 
> - chromedriver - 2.32 
>  But after getting new updates 
> - chrome browser - 62.0.3202.94 
> - chromedriver - 2.33.506120 
> scripts started failing.

**My Guess** : After fixing issue 2017 the previous issue 1852 is broken again as per [release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.33/notes.txt).

Can someone please help me to resolve this issue ?

Comment: @DebanjanB - I have also referred that [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el). But that didn't work for me. In my case element is not disabled, not hidden, not having any Overlay.