# selenium aria-activedescendant multiple select box java

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I need to automate the selection for a multidrop down box in selenium. The html code which comprises the dropdown is given below. The html code for each component is taken using firebug.

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input" id="s2id_autogen346" tabindex="-1" placeholder="" style="width: 269px;" aria-activedescendant="select2-result-label-367">
```

I have the aria-activedescendant="select2-result-label-367" value is changing when i change the select value in the list

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McpdD.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/703Km.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the `HTML` you have shared to select the multidrop down box you can use the following line of code :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='select2-search-field']//input[@class='select2-input' and contains(@id,'id_autogen')]")).click();
```

Comment: I have this erreur :
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input" id="s2id_autogen36" tabindex="-1" placeholder="" style="width: 10px;"> is not clickable at point (256, 183). Other element would receive the click: <ul class="select2-choices">...</ul>

Comment: this my htm form:

<ul class="select2-choices">  <li class="select2-search-field">    <label class="select2-offscreen" for="s2id_autogen12"></label>    <input type="text" class="select2-input" spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" id="s2id_autogen12" tabindex="-1" style="width: 269px;" placeholder="" aria-activedescendant="select2-result-label-231">  </li></ul>

Comment: Great !!! So your original Question of **automate the selection for a multidrop down box** is resolved now. Please **`Accept`** the **`Answer`** by clicking on the tick mark beside my Answer. For **Element  is not clickable at point** see this QA [Selenium Web Driver & Java. Element is not clickable at point (36, 72). Other element would receive the click:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el/44916498#44916498)

Comment: Can you help me to make this test please ?

Comment: how can i select KOKOKO value please :

<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable select2-highlighted" role="presentation"><div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-24" role="option"><span class="select2-match"></span>KOKOKO</div></li>

Comment: @rouis Can you raise a new Question with your new requirement please? Thanks