# python selenium throw element is not clickable at point (x,y) even though the element is clicked

Tags: python, selenium

When I'm trying to click an element i get the error but in reality the element is clicked.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("some url here")
start_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('start-button')
start_button.click()
```

Comment: You can delay WebDriverWait until element_to_be_clickable before clicking on the element. This way it will make sure if element is clickable or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Web Driver & Java. Element is not clickable at point (36, 72). Other element would receive the click:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el)

Comment: Post the url. You many need to use some JavaScript to apply the click