# selenium is not clickable at point (754, 28)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I keep getting:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:
>   Element  div class="tbc-ui-summary-container"
>   ng-transclude="summary">.../div> is not clickable at point (754, 28).
>   Other element would receive the click: input type="text"
>   ng-model="$ctrl.searchTerm" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 600 }"
>   on-enter-keydown="$ctrl.onPressEnterKey()"
>   on-esc-keydown="$ctrl.onPressEscKey()"
>   on-arrow-down-keydown="$ctrl.onPressArrowDownKey()"
>   on-arrow-up-keydown="$ctrl.onPressArrowUpKey()"
>   ng-change="$ctrl.onChange($ctrl.searchTerm)" placeholder="Search for
>   jockeys, trainers, horses, matches and more..."
>   ng-focus="$ctrl.setHighlightState(true)"
>   ng-blur="$ctrl.setHighlightState(false)" class="search-input
>   ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" hidden="">

I have tried to resolve with:

```
header1 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > ui-view > header > div')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", header).
```

Also:

```
clickMe1 = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '(//*[@class="tbc-ui-summary-container"])[%s]' % str(index + 1)))) action = ActionChains(driver) action.move_to_element(clickMe1).perform() 
clickMe1.click()
```

This has not worked for me

I then get:

```
search-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" hidden=
```

related unable to click message

How can I stop getting these unable to click at point error messages?

Script that works for a bit.. but then gets these error messages:

```
import collections
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
driver.maximize_window()


driver.get('https://www.tab.com.au/sports/betting/Soccer/competitions')



clickMe = wait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ('.tbc-ui-summary-container'))))



def page_counter():
    for x in range(1000):
        yield x

count = page_counter()



coupon_lables = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='tbc-ui-summary-container']")

coupon_lables = [index for index in range(len(coupon_lables))]


links = dict((next(count) + 1, e) for e in coupon_lables)
desc_links = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(links.items(), reverse=True))
for key, index in desc_links.items():
    driver.get('https://www.tab.com.au/sports/betting/Soccer/competitions')
    clickMe1 = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '(//*[@class="tbc-ui-summary-container"])[%s]' % str(index + 1))))
    header1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="search-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty"]')
    header2 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > ui-view > header > div > ng-transclude > search-input > div > div.search-input-wrapper > div.search-input-header > div.search-field > input')
    header3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="transcluded-content"]')
    header4 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="search-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty"]')
    header3 = driver.execute_script('arguments[0].hidden="true";', header1)
    header2 = driver.execute_script('arguments[0].hidden="true";', header2)
    header4 = driver.execute_script('arguments[0].hidden="true";', header4)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", clickMe1)
    clickMe1.click()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Web Driver & Java. Element is not clickable at point (36, 72). Other element would receive the click:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el)

Comment: @DebanjanB Worth noting I have tried solution 2 - driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", clickMe1) as well as solution 1      clickMe1 = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '(//*[@class="tbc-ui-summary-container"])[%s]' % str(index + 1))))    action = ActionChains(driver)
    action.move_to_element(clickMe1).perform() - Same error