# Selenium "unknown error" randomly

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm using Selenium to search for element's and click them (localhost website) and sometimes the code runs perfectly and sometimes I get an error right after the website loads or while loading.
Error:

> "Message: System.InvalidOperationException : unknown error: Element `<span _ngcontent-c8="" class="ui-link-button" fxlayout="row" fxlayoutalign="start center" ng-reflect-klass="ui-link-button" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-layout="row" ng-reflect-align="start center" style="flex-direction: row; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; max-height: 100%; place-content: center flex-start; align-items: center;">...</span>` is not clickable at point (219, 113). Other element would receive the click: `<ui-spinner _ngcontent-c0="" _nghost-c1="">...</ui-spinner>`
>         (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.84)
>         (Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522940
>    (1a76f96f66e3ca7b8e57d503b4dd3bccfba87af1),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)"

My driver has implicit wait for 60 seconds so I don't think it because the site isn't loading fast enough.

```
   public class Driver
    {
        public static IWebDriver driver { get; set; }

        public static void WaitForElementUpTo(int seconds = 60)
        {
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds));
        }
    }
```

I'm using Chrome driver.

Comment: Wait for the element you want to click to be visible, seems another element receives the click `ui-spinner`, you need some wait.

Comment: I am waiting (60 seconds)

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Web Driver & Java. Element is not clickable at point (36, 72). Other element would receive the click:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el/44916498#44916498)

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error

Comment: The message is certainly implying that  you didn't wait long enough..."Other element would receive the click: <ui-spinner..."   that ui-spinner element suggests that there's a control up on the page that's spinning.  You might consider waiting for that to go away.

Answer (score 0):

Try using explicit wait wand wait till element is clickable

Answer (score 0):

```
 Other element would receive the click: <ui-spinner _ngcontent-c0="" _nghost-c1="">...</ui-spinner>
```

This would suggest that you have a loading spinner blocking the click to your element. As others have suggested, use an explicit wait:

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsClickable(By.Id("abc")))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Momkey Tester.
Im trying to pass an element that should be clickable after the spinner stops working (using xpath) but i get the same error (randomly).
is there way to pause for lets say 15 seconds and resume (like Thread.Sleep(15))

Comment: Well you could just use Thread.Sleep() if that is all you want to do, but using an explicit wait is the "correct" way to do it.

Comment: I think an Implicit wait will make the webdriver wait until the element is available, but it may still be in an unclickable state (i.e. if the spinner hasn't disappeared yet).

Comment: From the documentation: WARNING: Do not mix implicit and explicit waits. Doing so can cause unpredictable wait times. For example setting an implicit wait of 10 seconds and an explicit wait of 15 seconds, could cause a timeout to occur after 20 seconds.

Comment: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
IWebElement el = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsClickable(By.Id("myid")));

Comment: Tried what you have suggested but im still getting the same error.

Comment: Tried adding    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.Id("//* [@id=\"spinner12\"]/div")));

And it didnt work aswell

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162590/discussion-between-monkeytester-and-udi).

Answer (score 0):

Finally i used this function in order to wait for the spinner to nolonger exist and then continue with the scenario :

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
    wait.Until<bool>((d) =>
    {
        try
        {
            IWebElement element1 = d.FindElement(By.CssSelector(element));
            return false;
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```