# Element not clickable after storing the value in the List?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am not able to click element after storing the webelements in the List collection.

```js
 List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='dropdown-menu']/li/a"));
        System.out.println(links.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++) {
            String text = links.get(i).getText();
            System.out.println(text);
            if (text.contentEquals("CSS")) {
                links.get(i).click();
                break;
            }
        }
```

I used action class to find the drop down menu and the drop down is developed in bootstrap.
Below mentioned full error:

```html
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (183, 560)
  (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.132)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 71 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:00:17 -0800'
System info: host: 'RAV-LAP-503', ip: '192.168.2.55', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b), userDataDir=C:\Users\SAJITH~1.KUM\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir13096_30556}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=63.0.3239.132, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: 697295b27acff024727ad8efd7d66c14
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:638)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:274)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)
 at Yahoo.bootstrap.main(bootstrap.java:30)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Comment: My guess would be that because the drop-down menu is not first clicked, the list elements are not exposed, therefore the error message that they are not clickable.  Without seeing the HTML code, I can't be sure.  Is it a select element?

Answer (score 0):

As you see the error as :

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (183, 560)
```

I have pointed you towards the solution as in [Selenium Web Driver & Java. Element is not clickable at point (36, 72). Other element would receive the click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el/44916498#44916498)

But your main issue is the *version compatibility* among the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using *chromedriver=2.28.455520*
- Release Notes of [chromedriver=2.28.455520](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) clearly mentions the following :

> Various updates to work with Chrome 57+

- You are using *chrome=63.0.3239.132*
- To work with *chrome=63.x* you have to use *ChromeDriver 2.34* as the Release Notes of [ChromeDriver 2.34](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) clearly mentions :

> Supports Chrome v61-63

---

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  *ChromeDriver v2.34*.
- Downgrade *Chrome* to  *Chrome v57.x* level.