# BrowserStack error occurs when running selenium tests: Element is not clickable at point (48, -414)

Tags: scala, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I run selenium tests via BrowserStack, the following error occurs quite a few times:

```
Element is not clickable at point (48, -414)
```

Has anyone else come across the same issue?

Thanks
Jackie

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Web Driver & Java. Element is not clickable at point (36, 72). Other element would receive the click:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el)

Answer (score 0):

I have now solved this problem. The solution was to set the real mobile device setting to false.

Thanks