# How to handle error throws from selenium hq js

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am using example code from seleniumHQ (https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs)

```
const {Builder, By, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');

let driver = new Builder()
    .forBrowser('firefox')
    .build();

driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr');
driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');
driver.findElement(By.name('btnK')).click();
driver.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search'), 1000);
driver.quit();
```

On line `driver.findElement(By.name('btnK')).click();` there is sometimes error with slow render/loading of element, element is not clicable.

How to handle this error and repeat click if `element is not clicable error throws`?

Thank you for any help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Web Driver & Java. Element is not clickable at point (36, 72). Other element would receive the click:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el)

Comment: Sure :-D JAVA != JAVASCRIPT

Comment: Can you try `driver.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search'), 1000).catch((err)=>{//code to retry })`