# C#+ Selenium: click on submit

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I use C# with Selenium and testing the application running on Chrome at the moment but hoping to expand all browsers. So I try couple code below and they're not working on the click action. I use XPath, but it throws an exception saying there is no element found in the form. I don't put submit on the form.  I also use the other normal way, but it does not submit anything:

```
    <div id="textAreaSection">
        <div class="textArea">
            <label><b>TextArea:</b></label><br>
            <textarea id="textAreaText" rows="14" cols="40"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="surveyBtn">
            <input id="inputSubmit" onClick="inputText()" type="submit" value="Input Text">
        </div>
   </div>
```

I try this, but no clicking or submitting anything after it's executed:

```
IWebElement tagElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("inputSubmit"));
tagElement.Submit();
```

I try XPath, but the exception is thrown saying that it cannot find an element in the form:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='inputSubmit']")).Submit();
```

**Update: 1**

I try to use WebDriverWait suggested by LoflinA but still throws an exception about not clickable at point (387,590). Another element would receive the click:

```
public void WaitUntilClickable(IWebElement elementLocator, int timeout)
{
    try
    {
        WebDriverWait waitForElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout));
        waitForElement.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(elementLocator));
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Element with locator: '" + elementLocator + "' was not found in current context page.");
        throw;
    }
}
```

And here is the caller block:

```
    IWebElement tag = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='surveyBtn']/input[@id='inputSubmit']"));

    WaitUntilClickable(tag, 10);

    tag.Click();
```

**Update: 2**
Thanks to @chris-crush-code below code works!

```
 public void CallSubmitType(IWebElement tag, IWebDriver driver)
    {
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        string script = tag.GetAttribute("onClick");
        js.ExecuteScript(script);
    }

    [Then(@"SpecFlowTesting")]
    public void SpecFlowTesting(string expectedStr)
    {                        
        IWebElement tag = driver.FindElement(By.Id("inputSubmit"));
        CallSubmitType(tag, driver);

        IWebElement tagTextArea = webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("textAreaText"));
        string txt = tagTextArea.GetAttribute("value");
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedStr, txt);
    }
```

Comment: Did you try Click()-method?

Comment: i just try with click() and the exception says "unknown error: Element <input id="inputSubmit" onclick="inputText()" type="submit" value="Input Text"> is not clickable at point (387, 590). Other element would receive the click: <div class="secondBlock">...</div>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Web Driver & Java. Element is not clickable at point (36, 72). Other element would receive the click:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el)

Comment: when I searched on google, i didn't enounter this post. I will take a look although I use SpecFlow C# with Selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a recent update of chrome requires you to scroll to the clickable object. So:

```
var js = (IJavascriptExecutor)driver;
IWebElement obj = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='inputSubmit']"));
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", obj);

obj.Click();
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned receiving the error detailing that another element would receive the click, I am thinking that your page has not loaded completely prior to the action being attempted. Try the following to wait for the element to be clickable:

```
    // Wait Until Object is Clickable
    public static void WaitUntilClickable(IWebElement elementLocator, int timeout)
    {
        try
        {
            WebDriverWait waitForElement = new WebDriverWait(DriverUtil.driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            waitForElement.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(elementLocator));
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Element with locator: '" + elementLocator + "' was not found in current context page.");
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Also see: [Selenium Web Driver & Java. Element is not clickable at point (36, 72). Other element would receive the click:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: thank you for your depth analyst on the code.  I will try your code and let you know.

Comment: Is there some sort of overlay being placed on the page at load? Is there a new frame being created that needs to be switched to? I have experienced needing to click somewhere on the pageBody in order to allow clicking on any other element. Have you tried implementing a click anywhere else on this same page prior to this one being clicked?

Comment: This inputSubmit is on the main page.  there is no navigator or sidbar.  Just plain <html> </html> with <div>, <table>, <form>, are just simple elements as i try to learn web and SpecFlow Selenium.  Although there is other click on the hyper link but that is in different test case so it shouldn't be executed since I only focus on this specific test case for dealing with inputSubmit.  Also every time when the tested test case completes, the web driver will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

As per the `HTML` you have shared the `WebElement` clearly have a `onClick()` attribute so **Java** `click()` should work. But we are not sure if the `WebElement` is within a form or not to guarantee `submit()` method to work.

To `click()` on the button with `value` as `Input Text` you can try the following line of code :

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='surveyBtn']/input[@id='inputSubmit']")).Click();
```

Comment: I just try, but threw exception.

Comment: I try with your latest updates, but the same exception.  That element with Id inputSubmit is not in form tag.  Sorry I'm pretty new web so i was aware about using submit with form.  "An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: unknown error: Element <input id="inputSubmit" onclick="inputText()" type="submit" value="Input Text"> is not clickable at point (387, 590). Other element would receive the click: <div class="secondBlock">...</div>"

Comment: I meant, I was not aware of using submit with form.