# How to select element using ng-class in selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to automate web application which is AngularJs as frontend ,I am having HTML like below:

```
<div class="ui-grid-selection-row-header-buttons ui-grid-icon-ok ng-scope" ng-class="{'ui-grid-all-selected': grid.selection.selectAll}" ng-click="headerButtonClick($event)" ng-if="grid.options.enableSelectAll" role="button" tabindex="0"></div>
```

I want to select an element using ng-class attribute can any one help me out for doing these....

Comment: Any specific requirement to use _ng-class_ leaving aside _class_ ?

Comment: No such requirement ,i tried selecting using class but not able to find.And also the selection with ng-click is firing another event not the one desired becoz both are having same ng-click value.So I thought of going with ng-class.If it is possible or if it works with class can u please share thee working code of that...

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to click on the element you can use the following line of code :

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='ui-grid-selection-row-header-buttons ui-grid-icon-ok ng-scope']")).Click();
```

As the *WebElement* is an *Angular WebElement* you may require to induce *WebDriverWait* through either of the ways as follows :

- Using *Until* :

  ```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
  IWebElement myDynamicElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>(d => d.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='ui-grid-selection-row-header-buttons ui-grid-icon-ok ng-scope']")));
  myDynamicElement.Click();
  ```
- Using *wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsClickable(By.by))* :

  ```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
  IWebElement myDynamicElement = wait.wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsClickable(By.XPath("//div[@class='ui-grid-selection-row-header-buttons ui-grid-icon-ok ng-scope']")));
  myDynamicElement.Click();
  ```

Update :
As per the error you are seeing *Element is not clickable at point (245, 310)* see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el/44916498#44916498).

Comment: I am getting error as follows:Test Name:                                           

Result Message: 
System.InvalidOperationException : unknown error: Element <div class="ui-grid-selection-row-header-buttons ui-grid-icon-ok ng-scope" ng-class="{'ui-grid-all-selected': grid.selection.selectAll}" ng-click="headerButtonClick($event)" ng-if="grid.options.enableSelectAll" role="button" tabindex="0"></div> is not clickable at point (245, 310). Other element would receive the click: <div class="ui-widget-overlay" id="mainpagediv">...</div>

Comment: Updated my answer with some inputs.

Comment: I tried all the ways which you mentioned  but I am still getting exception like it is not clickable at (245,310).Can u share the code if it works for you,Any help is highly appreciated....

Comment: Thanks for the post,But it  doesn't work for me  if you have any other way of doing like with ng-class or with class ,Please do post..