# Clicking on specific item in the list in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a list in which it is having a list of items and I want to click on the specific element having (SOP) as text. I want to check whether the text exists in the list or not and want to click on the specific item if present.

Can anyone please share the code for that? I am a newbie in Selenium.

My HTML code for selecting list of items:

```
 IList<IWebElement> element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[@ng-click='selectButtonClick(row, $event)']")));
```

Comment: Post your HTML in question, please.

Comment: Raw HTML code                                                                                   
                <div class="ui-grid-selection-row-header-buttons ui-grid-icon-ok ng-scope" ng-class="{'ui-grid-row-selected': row.isSelected}" ng-click="selectButtonClick(row, $event)" role="button" tabindex="0">&nbsp;</div>

Comment: Html code for selecting list of elements:                                                                    IList<IWebElement> element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[@ng-click='selectButtonClick(row, $event)']")));

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select element using ng-class in selenium C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48575591/how-to-select-element-using-ng-class-in-selenium-c-sharp)