# Unable To Select Previous Month In Calendar

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to select 2 Jan 2020 in calendar but i am not able to select past month with future year.

For example current month is February.  I can easily select any month after February .

This is working with upcoming month's but this code is not working with past months if i am giving future year then January is not selected

```
//-SCHEDULING SECTION 
            if ("Required".equals(regType)) {
                String dayValue;
                String dd = "";
                String mm = "";
                String yyyy = "";
                String hhMM = "";
                if (dueDate != null && dueDate.trim().length() > 0 && dueDate.contains("Days")) {
                    if (dueDate.contains(" ")) {
                        String[] day = dueDate.split(" ");
                        dayValue =day[0];
                        isDisplayed(numDaysRadioLocator, 10);
                        click(numDaysRadioLocator);

                        Select sel=new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("rvDaysFromSelect")));
                        sel.selectByValue(dayValue);

                        isDisplayed(schedulingContinueButton, 10);
                        click(schedulingContinueButton);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Date format not as per requirement so we proceeding  without due date");
                        isDisplayed(schedulingContinueButton, 10);
                        click(schedulingContinueButton);
                    }
                } else if (dueDate.equals("None")) {
                    System.out.println("\t" +  "\t" + "No due date");
                    isDisplayed(schedulingContinueButton, 10);
                    click(schedulingContinueButton);
                } else if (dueDate != null && dueDate.trim().length() > 0 && dueDate.contains("/")) {
                    String[] calendarData = dueDate.split("/");
                    mm = calendarData[0];
                    dd = calendarData[1];
                    yyyy = calendarData[2];
                    hhMM =calendarData[3];

                    isDisplayed(selectSpecificDate,10);
                    click(selectSpecificDate);

                    isDisplayed(dueDateCalendarIcon,10);
                    click(dueDateCalendarIcon);
                    Actions action = new Actions(driver);                   
                    //-Second we are selecting year from calendar
                    new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("(//div[@class='xdsoft_datetimepicker xdsoft_noselect xdsoft_']//div[@class='xdsoft_label xdsoft_year'])[" + calendarDivNo +"]")));
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='xdsoft_datetimepicker xdsoft_noselect xdsoft_']//div[@class='xdsoft_label xdsoft_year'])[" + calendarDivNo +"]")).click();
                    WebElement waitForYearVisibility = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='xdsoft_select xdsoft_yearselect xdsoft_scroller_box']//div[contains(text(),'" + yyyy +"')])[" + calendarDivNo +"]"));
                    action.moveToElement(waitForYearVisibility).build().perform();
                    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("(//div[@class='xdsoft_select xdsoft_yearselect xdsoft_scroller_box']//div[contains(text(),'" + yyyy +"')])[" + calendarDivNo +"]")));
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='xdsoft_select xdsoft_yearselect xdsoft_scroller_box']//div[contains(text(),'" + yyyy +"')])[" + calendarDivNo +"]")).click(); 

                    //-First we are selecting month from calendar
                    new WebDriverWait(driver, 25).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("(//div[@class='xdsoft_datepicker active']//div[@class='xdsoft_label xdsoft_month'])[" + calendarDivNo +"]")));
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='xdsoft_datepicker active']//div[@class='xdsoft_label xdsoft_month'])[" + calendarDivNo +"]")).click();

                    WebElement waitForMonthVisibility = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='xdsoft_select xdsoft_monthselect xdsoft_scroller_box']//div[contains(text(),'" + mm +"')])[" + calendarDivNo +"]"));
                    action.moveToElement(waitForMonthVisibility).build().perform();
                    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("(//div[@class='xdsoft_select xdsoft_monthselect xdsoft_scroller_box']//div[contains(text(),'" + mm +"')])[" + calendarDivNo +"]")));
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='xdsoft_select xdsoft_monthselect xdsoft_scroller_box']//div[contains(text(),'" + mm +"')])[" + calendarDivNo +"]")).click();
                    //-Third we are selecting day from calendar
                    List<WebElement> allDays=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='xdsoft_calendar']/table//tbody//tr//td"));
                    for(WebElement ele:allDays) {   
                        String date=ele.getText();
                        if(date.equalsIgnoreCase(dd)){ 
                            action.click(ele).build().perform();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    //-Finally we are selecting time from calendar
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    WebElement waitForTimeVisbibility = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='xdsoft_time_box xdsoft_scroller_box']//div[@class='xdsoft_time_variant']/div[contains(text(),'" + hhMM +"')])[" + calendarDivNo +"]"));
                    action.moveToElement(waitForTimeVisbibility).build().perform();
                    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("(//div[@class='xdsoft_time_box xdsoft_scroller_box']//div[@class='xdsoft_time_variant']/div[contains(text(),'" + hhMM +"')])[" + calendarDivNo +"]")));
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='xdsoft_time_box xdsoft_scroller_box']//div[@class='xdsoft_time_variant']/div[contains(text(),'" + hhMM +"')])[" + calendarDivNo +"]")).click();

                    isDisplayed(schedulingContinueButton, 10);
                    click(schedulingContinueButton);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Date format not as per requirement so we proceeding  without due date");
                    isDisplayed(schedulingContinueButton, 10);
                    click(schedulingContinueButton);
                }
            }
```

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: @Pradeephebbar This is a exception org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="0">...</div> is not clickable at point (481, 307). Other element would receive the click: <span>...</span>
  (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.132)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 78 milliseconds
Bu

Comment: Can you post your click method

Comment: @Pradeephebbar  This is a code  Please check above shared code after this line   //-First we are selecting month from calendar    First i am clicking on month then after i am trying to scroll till given month

Comment: @Pradeephebbar   First i need to scroll in list because value is dynamic i am  trying to scroll in month drop down    WebElement waitForMonthVisibility = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='xdsoft_select xdsoft_monthselect xdsoft_scroller_box']//div[contains(text(),'" + mm +"')])[" + calendarDivNo +"]"));
                    action.moveToElement(waitForMonthVisibility).build().perform();

Comment: Can you try `JavascriptExecutor ` click once

Comment: @Pradeephebbar  I have already used JavascriptExecutor  and i was getting same error   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="0">...</div> is not clickable at point (481, 307). Other element would receive the click: <span>...</span> (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.132) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 78 milliseconds

Comment: WebDriverWait waitForElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
waitForElement.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("locator")));
Use this before click

Comment: @Pradeephebbar Actually problem is when we click on calendar and after when we click on month  then  current month is visible on top and for viewing  passed  month we need to scroll manually in calendar view .

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el/44916498

Comment: Can you post a link to the page?

Comment: @Pradeephebbar  Thanks for sharing link  but i have tried all steps and every time i am getting same error   we don't have id 
 we need to use same xpath shared on above in code 
    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="0">...</div> is not clickable at point (481, 307). Other element would receive the click: <span>...</span> (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.132) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120

Comment: @JeffC  Can you please suggest ?

Comment: @Pradeephebbar This is DOM elements  <div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="0">January</div> == $0
<div class="xdsoft_option xdsoft_current" data-value="1">February</div>
<div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2">March</div>       When we click on calendar then February is highlighted on top in month scroll bar

Comment: Can you please post the website url

Comment: @pradeephebbar please ignore last share website  we are working on staging website and we can't access staging website outside the office

Comment: /Where should i navigate to see the calendar?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Web Driver & Java. Element is not clickable at point (36, 72). Other element would receive the click:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el)

Comment: @DebanjanB please see in my xpath I am always picking unique value..

Comment: @Pradeephebbar  Any update on this?

Comment: I have updated my answer , please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this scenario..

I have change drop down pixel position at the time of execution with Java script.

Now I have set drop down pixel position 0 at run time.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the calendar locator and i can see two matches for every locator inside the calendar. I believe you are trying to click the first one and its a hidden one so you are getting the `WebDriverException: unknown error`.

you can try the below two locators and i believe this will help you.

```
1. (//div[@class='xdsoft_monthpicker']//button[@class='xdsoft_prev'])[2]
```

You can also identify the locator by using current month like this

```
2.(//span[text()='February']/parent::div/parent::div/button[@class='xdsoft_prev'])[2]
```

Here i am identifying the previous month element by using the 'February' text and i order to use it you have replace the 'February' with the current month to identify the previous month.

3. You can use this locator also and you may need to change the value based on month.You have to click on the month dropdown first.

   ```
   (//div[contains(@class,'monthselect xdsoft_scroller_box')]//div[@class='xdsoft_option ' and text()='March'])[2]
   ```

But i tried my best to frame locator without using index but no luck.

If the count value is changing on each click and every time you need to select last item , then try like this.

```
public void clickPreviousMonth() {
        Thread.sleep(30000);
        List<WebElement> previuosMonthElements = context.getDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='xdsoft_monthpicker']//button[@class='xdsoft_prev']"));
        int index = previuosMonthElements.size();
        String modifiedXpath = "(//div[@class='xdsoft_monthpicker']//button[@class='xdsoft_prev']["+index+"])";
        Thread.sleep(30000);
        context.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(modifiedXpath)).click();
    }
```

*I have used the sleep directly , you can try with `fluentwait`

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply    . I have checked with all above options but my issue not resolved and i am getting same error  org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="0">...</div> is not clickable at point (481, 307). .   Yes you are right we have 2 calendar in same page  if you will see in my shared code  my xpath is dynamic and my code is working fine with current and future months .  I have facing issue only with Passed month .

Comment: Can you please suggest me is there any way to scroll month drop down till top position .  Because if we will scroll up  to maximum then this will work.

Comment: As per my execution or client requirement we need to  read month name from excel sheet .  Suppose  Currently April month is running and client send January  in excel sheet and in this condition above code will not work because as per above code we are selecting last previous month .    Can you please send me a solution like  if any month is running and we can easily select any month from past month