# Scroll until a specific point or element will be visible of page

Tags: selenium, rselenium

I have a button which I use the click element to press it. It is a show more button.

```
webElem$clickElement()
```

However in some pages the r selenium gives this error:

```
Selenium message:unknown error: Element <button class = "mybutton">...</button> is not clickable at point (462, 24). Other element would receive the click: <div id="etype">...</div>
```

Is there any idea if I can make RSelenium go to the specific point or if there is another option than click? Or generally scroll until the element is available?

Comment: `Other element would receive the click: <div id="etype">...</div>` There is another element blocking the click. Probably some popup or overlay. Close it and your script should work fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Web Driver & Java. Element is not clickable at point (36, 72). Other element would receive the click:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

`remDr$mouseMoveToLocation(webElement = webElem)`

before `webElem$clickElement()`.  If the element webElem is not on screen you can't click on it. You must move it into view with the method mouseMoveToLocation.