# Cucumber+Selenium: even when I dismiss dialog and wait before next action, test fails

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I'm using Java for my project and Page Object Model.

I have a test that is supposed to edit some content within a rich text editor, then click a button. But before the text editor is displayed, there is a dialog saying something like "what would you like to do?" and it has an "edit" button. So I did something like this:

```
Given user is on edit page
When dialog is displayed, user clicks on Edit
And user enters text in the editor
And user clicks on Save button 
Then edited content is displayed
```

I have page objects for each page, with locators initialized by PageFactory as:

```
PageFactory.initElements(new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, 20), pageObject);
```

and also locators and methods that interact with them are in the page objects like this:

```
@FindBy(css="span.saveLink span#editform-save a.buttonElement")
private WebElement saveLink;

public void saveEdits(){
    saveLink.click();
}
```

The weird thing is that my test keeps failing when trying to click on the save link (last step before the assertion) with this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <a role="button" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" href="/document/DOC1335" rel="nofollow" class="buttonElement">...</a> is not clickable at point (659, 563). Other element would receive the click: <div class="welcome-window dialog window-active window-setup" role="dialog">...</div>
```

I'm trying to find the `<div class="welcome-window dialog window-active window-setup" role="dialog">` element within the browser inspector but it doesn't seem to be there (even when the dialog is on screen), but I still believe the dialog has something to do with this.

The weird thing is that the test only fails when clicking on the save button, so the previous steps of clicking on "Edit" in the dialog and entering text in the editor are successful.

I set it up to get a screenshot of failed tests, and sometimes it's still showing the dialog and sometimes it's showing the editor (dialog dismissed). So I added an explicit wait (other than the wait added when initializing objects):

```
public void saveEdits(){
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(saveLink)).click();
}
```

However, this didn't help. When I view the test running it seems to fail as soon as the dialog is dismissed, with no wait at all.

I'm not sure what could be going on here...

Comment: Try re-instantiating your page object -after- you click the edit option on the dialog.

Comment: I did, but result is the same :(

Comment: Does the dialog exist in the same DOM as the main page?  It does sound based on your message that there is something "blocking" the save element, even if it's not visible.  I might next try a sleep for say five seconds, not as a permanent solution, but to see if it needs time for a blocker element to unload/clear.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. How can I check if the page and the dialog are in the same DOM?

Comment: When you bring up developer tools explore (chrome) does it show the dialog as part of the same source as the rest of the page beneath, or does it show only the HTML code for the dialog?  If the former, it's part of the same DOM.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Web Driver & Java. Element is not clickable at point (36, 72). Other element would receive the click:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el)

Comment: @BillHileman it's definitely in the same DOM then...