# Getting Error while selecting a value from a drop down popup

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: Element  is not clickable at point (951.5,591.1083450317383) because another element  obscures it

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read  how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please share block of code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Web Driver & Java. Element is not clickable at point (36, 72). Other element would receive the click:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el)

Answer (score -1):

check with xpath and wait statement 
try it any wait statement like Thread.sleep(millseconds);
or explicit, implicit.