# How to click on a link with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on this link using click():

```
<a id="export-button" class="pull-right" @click="exportFile('/en/my-investments/list.xlsx')">
    <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> Download Selected List
</a>
```

but it says the element is not clickable... any idea?

Comment: Share how you're trying to click

Comment: Like @Andersson said, can you share some of your code? What is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Web Driver & Java. Element is not clickable at point (36, 72). Other element would receive the click:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el)

Answer (score 0):

You may use action class to click your element,

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='export-button']")).click().perform()
```