# Which locator I can use to click the span element through selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

Which locator can I use for the below?

```
<span class="tile-name ng-binding">Payment Partner</span>
```

Update from OP's comments:

Code trial 1:

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//span[text()='Payment Partner']").click();
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible;
```

Code trial 2:

```
driver.findElementByCssSelector("Payment Partner").click();
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"Payment Partner"}
```

Code trial 3:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath ("//span[text()='Payment Partner']')")));
```

Comment: Share your XPath and CSS selector

Comment: Share html in text format or url and code you tried

Comment: @Andersson please check my new update

Comment: @sers please check my new update

Comment: @Catia You should share your code attempts as well

Comment: @Catia , try to implement [waits](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits)

Comment: @Andersson I have already done that with no success:  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

Comment: @Catia , only this line? This line only defines the instance of `WebDriverWait`, but does nothing more actually

Comment: There an extra single quote and parenthesis in your selector

Comment: @Andersson that has been corrected but still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to to find the `<span>` tag, as the element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solution:

- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@class='tile-name ng-binding' and contains(.,'Payment Partner')]"))).click();
  ```
- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("span.tile-name.ng-binding"))).click();
  ```

### Update

As per the error update to invoke `click()` you can use the following solution:

- `xpath`:

  ```
  WebElement myElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@class='tile-name ng-binding' and contains(.,'Payment Partner')]")));
  ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", myElement);
  ```

You can find a detailed discussion in [Selenium Web Driver & Java. Element is not clickable at point (36, 72). Other element would receive the click:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions but none of the above works please see error:    Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <span class="tile-name ng-binding">...</span> is not clickable at point (152, 202). Other element would receive the click: <span ng-show="tile.behavior.className == 'entity-tile'" class="">...</span>
  (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)

Comment: @Catia Checkout my answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: It worked with the updated solution.... Great job thank you so much, been stuck for days on this one.

Answer (score 0):

**Following are variance that you can use for above HTML line :**

1. Xpath : `//span[text()='Payment Partner']`
2. Xpath : `//span[@class='tile-name ng-binding']`
3. Xpath : `//span[contains(@class,'tile-name')]`
4. Xpath : `//span[contains(@class,'ng-binding')]`
5. Xpath : `//span[contains(@class,'tile-name') and text()='Payment Partner']`
6. CssPath : `span[class='tile-name ng-binding']`

I can add more If there would be parent element.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: can you please share little more HTML code ? and your selenium code as well ? It will help us to find error.

Comment: Please check my comments previously shared.