# How to locate a complicated tag without id name or value?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Hi please help i have to find the xpath of this

```
<button _ngcontent-c27="" aria-label="VALIDATE" color="primary" fxflex="" mat-raised-button="" type="submit" class="mat-raised-button mat-primary" style="flex: 1 1 0%; box-sizing: border-box;"><span class="mat-button-wrapper"> VALIDATE </span><div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple" matripple=""></div><div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div></button>
```

but as i copy the xpath

```
/html/body/app-root/app-side-nav/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/main/app-otp/app-page-container/div/form/div/div/form/div/div[1]/button
```

then when i use it the console error NoSuchElementException

this is my code in selenium thanks in advace

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/app-side-nav/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/main/app-otp/app-page-container/div/form/div/div/form/div/div[1]/button")).click();
```

[HTML Button please click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1yXK.png)

Comment: Can you paste a simplified version of your HTML? (Just the relevant tags, no need to include the contents such as text etc...)

Comment: Hi @Isma can you teach me how i am just new in selenium webdriver thanks

Comment: I think you need to post your html, otherwise is difficult to know what is happening

Comment: Hi @Isma i already added the html

Comment: your html doesn't contain `<button>`, dynamic content?

Comment: Hi @ewwink i already put the <button> thanks

Comment: @ReneAlano As your code trial was in Java I have replaced the `C#` tag with `Java`. Please review the edit and confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so to locate (and possibly invoke `click()`) you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element To Be Clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.mat-raised-button.mat-primary[aria-label='VALIDATE']>span.mat-button-wrapper"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='mat-raised-button mat-primary' and @aria-label='VALIDATE']/span[@class='mat-button-wrapper']"))).click();
  ```

---

### Update

As you are facing the error *...unknown error: Element is not clickable at point...* you can use either of the following solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  WebElement my_css_element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.mat-raised-button.mat-primary[aria-label='VALIDATE']>span.mat-button-wrapper")));
  ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", my_css_element);
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  WebElement my_xpath_element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='mat-raised-button mat-primary' and @aria-label='VALIDATE']/span[@class='mat-button-wrapper']")));
  ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", my_xpath_element);
  ```

### Reference

You can find a related discussion in

- [Selenium Web Driver & Java. Element is not clickable at point (36, 72). Other element would receive the click:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el)

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB i use your solutions i have encountered this what should i do   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <span class="mat-button-wrapper">...</span> is not clickable at point (677, 432)

Comment: @ReneAlano Checkout my answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: @Hi DebanjanB it works thanks a lot! then for me to understand what did you just did how it works?

Comment: @ReneAlano check out my answer update and let me know if any questions.

Answer (score 1):

I hope these Three helps,

```
//button[@type='submit']
//*[contains(@type,'submit')]
//button[contains(text(),'VALIDATE')]
```

if Not try to post the HTML Code here so it will be helpful or, Check This Article try more on Yourself - `https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html`

Comment: Hi @koushick its not working ill try to read 1st the article you posted thanks!

Answer (score 1):

find with multiple attribute use `[@type=... and @class=...]`

```
//button[@type='submit' and @class='mat-raised-button mat-primary']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to automate website built on angular framework. In angular same div is used for multiple purpose. Developers just change binding and use the same button for multiple purpose.

If you share complete webpage html it would be a great help.

Just Check few things may be that help:

1. Web element is visible on page.(css properties like display:none makes element disappear from page.It is still present in DOM but web driver can't find it)
2. It is not loaded from jquery or ajax. if Yes, then Maybe you need to add webdriver wait for that.

Exact solution is depending on your complete web page.

Answer (score 0):

First as a practice its better to use relative xpath, It will help you to reuse your code when new changes added.

Second if there are no ID , Name or any specific element locator to handle, Then you have to try for attribute like

```
`//button[contains(text(),'Validate')]`

`//button[@type='submit']`
```

`//button[@aria-label='VALIDATE']`       etc.

Comment: Hi @SDK_90 its not working  Console: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Comment: Hi @ReneAlano, There may be multiple reasons. delay time , element name is incorrect in script (case sensitive), Or actually element not visible within active window area but visible within page (you need to add scroll down). etc.

First check locator name