# "Element is not clickable at point” New Relic

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, newrelic

I am having some struggle with my Selenium JS in New relic. I am trying to click an element and I am keeping get back the error "Element is not clickable at point". The solutions at the tread [Selenium Web Driver & Java. Element is not clickable at point (x, y). Other element would receive the click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y-other-elem) are not really applicable to NewRelic.
The snippet I am using is

```
.then(function() {
  log(26, 'clickElement "//form[@id=\'giftcard-form\']/div[3]/div/button"');
  return $browser.waitForAndFindElement(By.xpath("//form[@id=\'giftcard-form\']/div[3]/div/button"), DefaultTimeout); })
 .then(function (el) { el.click(); })
```

I don't see anything wrong with the code and the element is visible on the page.

![enter image description here][1]

Any suggestions? it seems a common issue but I didn't have luck with the solutions offered in the other thread 
Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: The difference is that the questions around this topic don't address specifically selenium on New Relic frame work. The script is running properly with my local dev environment but fails with New Relic. I spent a lot of hours trying to find solutions and work around. @ DebanjanB if you have the solution please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

waitForAndFindElement will wait only for element present. It will not wait for element visibility.

Try by waiting for the visibility of the element,

```
.then(function() {
  log(26, 'clickElement "//form[@id=\'giftcard-form\']/div[3]/div/button"');
 return $browser.wait($driver.until.elementIsVisible($browser.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id=\'giftcard-form\']/div[3]/div/button"))));
  }).then(function (el) { 
             el.click();
  })
```

If you are getting timeout error, then scroll to view and click.

```
.then(function() {
  log(26, 'clickElement "//form[@id=\'giftcard-form\']/div[3]/div/button"');
  return $browser.waitForAndFindElement(By.xpath("//form[@id=\'giftcard-form\']/div[3]/div/button"), DefaultTimeout); })
.then(function (el) { 
     $browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", el);
     el.click();
})
```

If the scroll doesn't help, then at last go with javascript click,

```
.then(function() {
  log(26, 'clickElement "//form[@id=\'giftcard-form\']/div[3]/div/button"');
  return $browser.waitForAndFindElement(By.xpath("//form[@id=\'giftcard-form\']/div[3]/div/button"), DefaultTimeout); })
.then(function (el) { 
     $browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", el);
})
```

Comment: The first snippet did the trick after increasing the timeout to 180000 ms