# How to click on the DASHBOARD tab to switch to it in the same webpage

Tags: scala, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am using selenium in scala to download some files automatically. I was able to login to the website but after that I was not able to move to the "Dashboard tab" by using it's div id. The error thrown is "Unable to locate element". There are two tabs named "home" and "Dashboard" in that webpage. After login, I want to move to "Dashboard" tab. I have tried everything available online but still not able to locate the tab element to click. Can someone help me out with this ? The html source that I am using is as follows

```
<div id="isc_35" eventproxy="DASHBOARD" role="tab" onfocus="if(event.target!=this)return;isc.EH.focusInCanvas(DASHBOARD,true);" onblur="if(window.isc)isc.EH.blurFocusCanvas(DASHBOARD,true);" tabindex="-1" style="position: absolute; left: 88px; top: 0px; width: 105px; height: 26px; z-index: 201080; box-sizing: border-box; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;" onscroll="return DASHBOARD.$lh()"><div id="isc_36" eventproxy="DASHBOARD" style="POSITION:relative;display:inline-block;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;width:100%;vertical-align:top;VISIBILITY:inherit;Z-INDEX:201080;CURSOR:pointer;"><table width="105px" height="26px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr><td class="tabButtonTop" tabindex="-1" onfocus="DASHBOARD.$47()" valign="center" nowrap="true" align="center">DASHBOARD</td></tr></tbody></table></div></div>
```

Comment: I am using isc_35 as an id to find this tab

Comment: what did you try: ~ "I have tried everything available online" ~, Also what is the HTML of the HOME button? are you sure `id="isc_35"` is unique?

Comment: @MosheSlavin - I have tried using xpath, css selector, classname etc. I have also tried using wait before clicking. I have also tried clicking with Actions. Yes, I am sure id isc_35 is unique.

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the *tab* with text as **DASHBOARD** as the element is a *dynamic* element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("td.tabButtonTop[onfocus^='DASHBOARD']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//td[@class='tabButtonTop' and starts-with(@onfocus,'DASHBOARD')][contains(., 'DASHBOARD')]"))).click();
  ```

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB - I tried it out but received the following error :
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <td nowrap="true" class="tabButtonTop" align="center" valign="center" onfocus="....$47()">DASHBOARD</td> is not clickable at point (140, 70). Other element would receive the click: <span style="display:inline-block;background-size:100% 100%;background-image:url(&quot;https://ford-ddlive.clifford-thames.com/datadistribution/sc/skins/ford/images/blank.gif&quot;);width:3200px;height:2400px;vertical-align:text-top"></span>

Comment: You haven't applied _WebDriverWait_. Induce _WebDriverWait_ for **element to be clickable** and let me know the status.

Comment: I have used WebDriverWait as follows :
val someElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//td[@class='tabButtonTop' and starts-with(@onfocus,'DASHBOARD')][contains(., 'DASHBOARD')]"))).click()

Is there any issue with this?

Comment: Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status. Ensure you use **elementToBeClickable** and nothing else.

Comment: I have tried element to be clickable as well but still I am getting the following error:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <td nowrap="true" class="tabButtonTop" align="center" valign="center" onfocus="....$47()">DASHBOARD</td> is not clickable at point (140, 70). Other element would receive the click.

Comment: I have tried both cssSelector and the xpath. But, both of them gave the same error. I am not able to figure out the issue.

Comment: Could you please suggest what could be the issue?

Comment: It is a typical _waiter_ issue. Check this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el/44916498#44916498) to solve _Element is not clickable at point_

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I will look into it.