# Element is not clickable because another element obscures it

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, click

the function:

```
def twoclicks(idoutter,idinner):
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@id," + idoutter + ") and @value='...']"))).click()
    sleep(5)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, idinner))).click()
```

This function is used to click an element then have a pop up a few seconds later and click an element of the popup.

I keep getting that error although i tried adding `sleep()` in my function and it's inconsistent as in i get it at times and i don't at others.

My previous function was:

```
def twoclicks(idoutter,idinner):
    outter = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@id," + idoutter + ") and @value='...']")
    outter.click()
    sleep(10)
    driver.find_element_by_id(idinner).click()
     sleep(7)
```

although my second function is a bad practice and the first one is supposed to be an improvement but i didn't get that exception using my second one.How can i adjust my first shared function to get rid of that error.

kindly note the code is a continuous call for similar functions like :

```
twoclicks("'button1'", 'button2')
twoclicks("'button3'", 'button4')
```

The div obscurint it is :

```
<div class="rich-mpnl-mask-div-opaque rich-mpnl-mask-div" id="PWBFormID:managerModalPanelDiv" style="z-index: -1;"><button class="rich-mpnl-button" id="PWBFormID:managerModalPanelFirstHref"></button></div>
```

it's in grey in the html(when inspecting).

I saw many methods like using `execute_script()` to block the div with the shared class above but the issue is i'm using a function for it and have dozens of buttons that won't have that issue or potentially have it with a different class which is making getting rid of such cases without manually writing a code for them alone case by case outside my `twoclicks()` function very difficult.

Comment: Does this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el/44916498#44916498) helps you?

Comment: @DebanjanB i have seen that answer yet found nothing in it that would explain why my initial function worked fine but the "improved" version is throwing that exception specially that i'm new.

Comment: Umm, I still don't see you handling the `pop up` properly. Do you need to click within the `pop up` for it to disappear or it vanishes itself? Possibly `pop up` causing you the issue

Comment: A new window pops up where i have to click on some element on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wait until Javascript to completed. Try wait method below:

```
def waitforload():
    wait.until(lambda d: d.execute_script(
        'return (document.readyState == "complete" || document.readyState == "interactive")'))


def twoclicks(idoutter, idinner):
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@id," + idoutter + ") and @value='...']"))).click()
    waitforload()
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, idinner))).click()
    waitforload()
```