# Selenium: Unknown error unable to click a custom made drop down at a point though it is there

Tags: java, selenium

I tried to click custom made dropdown and select an element via cssSelector which throws an error as

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <div class="filter-option pull-left">...</div> is not clickable at point (1148, 603). Other element would receive the click: <a href="#CallFeedback" rel="tooltip" class="modelclick" style="background-color:#3eadea" onclick="CallFeedback('SupportRequest');return false;" data-original-title="Support Request">...</a>
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.108)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
```

code:

```
WebElement SiteType = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".control-group:nth-child(5) .filter-option"));
        SiteType.click();

        new WebDriverWait(driver,100).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='divProfileSetting']/div/div/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/div/ul/li[2]/a/span")));
        WebElement SiteTypeOption = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='divProfileSetting']/div/div/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/div/ul/li[2]/a/span"));
        SiteTypeOption.click();
```

I have tried through Xpath and Class as well as

```
 //class btn-group bootstrap-select span12 dropup open
        //dropdown-menu open
//div[@id='divProfileSetting']/div/div/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/button/div
```

HTML:

```
<div class="controls">
    <select class="selectpicker span12" id="ddlSiteTypeList" name="ddlSiteTypeList" style="display: none;">
    <option value="">-------Select SiteType-------</option>
    <option value="4">Academic</option>
    <option value="6">Article</option>
    <option value="22">Other</option>
    <option value="19">Q&amp;A</option>
    <option value="11">Review</option>
    <div class="btn-group bootstrap-select span12">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-id="ddlSiteTypeList" data-original-title="" title="">
       <div class="filter-option pull-left">-------Select SiteType-------</div>
       &nbsp;
       <div class="caret"></div>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu open">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="menu">
    <li rel="0" class="selected"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-original-title="" title=""><span class="text" data-original-title="" title="">-------Select SiteType-------</span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-ok check-mark" data-original-title="" title=""></i></a></li>
    <li rel="1"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-original-title="" title=""><span class="text" data-original-title="" title="">Academic</span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-ok check-mark" data-original-title="" title=""></i></a></li>
    <li rel="2"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-original-title="" title=""><span class="text" data-original-title="" title="">Article</span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-ok check-mark" data-original-title="" title=""></i></a></li>

    <li rel="16"><a tabindex="0" class="" style=""
```

Can someone help me with this

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19763087/4513879 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/44916498/4513879

Comment: please provide your html.

Comment: @Dhru'soni I have added it