# Python Selenium Unable to locate button class name

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I had a look at all the similar questions on SO but couldn't manage to solve my problem.
Selenium does not seem to locate a button I am trying to click on to load more the page before scraping.

In the picture below is the button I am trying to click on to load more the [page](https://www.sunsail.fr/location-bateau/mediterranee/grece/athenes#!date=2021-4-3&departureId=7094096&yachtId=7236&sortOrder=Prix%20%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8Bcroissant&showAllDepartures=false&ageClass=Tout&charterType=BGBC&hullType=Tout&length=Tout&numberOfCabins=Tout&numberOfDays=7&numberOfPassengers=2&totalPrice=1620) before doing some scraping (class name of button : btn btn-default)
[image]

What I have done:
I used Selenium's webdriver.
I tried waiting for at least 5 seconds for the page to load using sleep.
And lastly using the click() function.
I have inspired myself from this [tutorial](http://jonathansoma.com/lede/foundations/classes/friday%20sessions/advanced-scraping-form-submissions-completed/) (section : Using Selenium)

urlpage = '[theurl](https://www.sunsail.fr/location-bateau/mediterranee/grece/athenes#!date=2021-4-3&departureId=7094096&yachtId=7236&sortOrder=Prix%20%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8Bcroissant&showAllDepartures=false&ageClass=Tout&charterType=BGBC&hullType=Tout&length=Tout&numberOfCabins=Tout&numberOfDays=7&numberOfPassengers=2&totalPrice=1620)'

My code is the following :

```
 driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(urlpage)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn btn-default")
button.click()
```

I would appreciate if someone had an idea of what I am doing wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem probably comes from the fact that you are trying to find a class name by giving 2 class names ("btn" and "btn-default"). When I changed the line to

```
button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn-default")
```

it seemed to work just fine. Be aware that there are few elements with the class "btn-default" and it will return only the first one. You can use the function

```
find_elements_by_class_name(class_name)
```

to find all the elements with this class (will return a list object).

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I tried the following: button = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(["btn-default"])
print(button) It responded InvalidSelectorException: Given css selector expression ".['btn-default']" is invalid: SyntaxError: Document.querySelectorAll: '.['btn-default']' is not a valid selector

Comment: @colla My bad, when I wrote [class-name] I meant to use it as following:
find_elements_by_class_name("btn-default")

Comment: Netanel, I am having the following issue:ElementClickInterceptedException: Element <a class="btn btn-default"> is not clickable at point (488,566) because another element <p class="p1"> obscures it   do you know how this could be fixed ?

Comment: @colla not sure but found these 2 questions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58255396/elementclickinterceptedexception-message-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-x

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y-other-elem