# Clicking on a checkbox works the first time but not the second [Selenium]

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, automation

So there are invoices I need to issue.

First, I click on the checkbox to select all invoices on the current page. Then I click on the issue button, and finally approve them to be issued.

Once the current invoices issued, the ones on the next page appear automatically.

I want to repeat the same process for the next ones but I can't click on the checkbox as I did the first time. Nothing happens, it doesn't give any error. Just nothing happens.

Here is the html [image: html]

@King11 [image: ss]

```
time.sleep(8) --wait until invoice screen appears
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("i[class='ion-android-checkbox-outline-blank']").click() --selecting checkbox
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Sil')]").click() --clicking on the sent button
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Evet')]").click() --approve to sent
time.sleep(12) --wait till current invoices are sent and checkbox become re-eligible to select

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("i[class='ion-android-checkbox-outline-blank']").click() --select the check box second time. used javascript to eleminate GUI issues but it does not do clicking
```

Edit: I found the solution by writing a loop that refreshing the browser every time it issued invoices

```
def loopy(page_number):
        while (page_number>0):
                driver.refresh()
                time.sleep(5)

                element_1=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/app/main/app/div/div/e-arsiv/taslaklar/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/button")
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element_1)

                element_2=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/app/main/app/div/div/e-arsiv/taslaklar/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/ul/button[7]")
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element_2)

                driver.implicitly_wait(20)

                driver.find_element_by_css_selector ("uc-quick-filter[titleshort='3A'][type='3M']").click()

                driver.implicitly_wait(20)

                element_4=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/app/main/app/div/div/e-arsiv/taslaklar/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/ul/button[text()='e-Arşiv']")
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element_4)

                wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 40)

                temp = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//e-arsiv/taslaklar/div[4]/div[3]/div/div/i")))
                action= ActionChains(driver)
                action.click(temp).perform()

                element_5=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Sil')]")
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element_5)

                element_6=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Evet')]")
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element_6)

                driver.implicitly_wait(20)

                service=driver.find_element_by_id('serviceLoading').get_attribute("style")


                while (service=='display: none;'):

                        driver.refresh()
                        page_number=page_number-1
                        time.sleep(5)


                        break

                else:
                        time.sleep(2)
                        service=driver.find_element_by_id('serviceLoading').get_attribute("style")
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging and stepping through each step?

Comment: The last line is the one that is not working but I don't know how to debug it since it is a single line code and it should work. driver.find_element_by_css_selector("i[class='ion-android-checkbox-outline-blank']").click() -```

Comment: Create a variable and see if that variable is the item you want clicked. Such as `var temp = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("i[class='ion-android-checkbox-outline-blank']")`. See if that's the element you want and then call `temp.click();` to test if it does what it needs to do. Just try breaking it up into smaller parts to see whats the part that not working correctly for you.

Comment: It should be that variable since it is working properly in the second line, clicking on the checkbox. Don't you think?

Comment: Since those lines are the same, wouldn't it be easier to just make a variable of that line as in my previous comment, and just call `temp.click()` at those two lines? Also have you tried getting the element another way besides by css_selector?

Comment: Try clicking using different method. (link)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y-other-elem , when .click() doesn't work I use second method and it works like charm everytime. Hope it helps you.

Comment: You can also try to find the element by css selector this way: `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("i[class='ion-android-checkbox-outline-blank']"));` It wont hurt to try it out to see if you get a different result somehow. or use Actions if all else fails.

Comment: already tried executeScript but same happens. just tried temp.click(), also same happened. It does not give any error but also do not select the checkbox in the second time. I also tried xpath("/html/body/app/main/app/div/div//e-arsiv/taslaklar/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/i") but it is giving NoSuchElementException

Comment: try using xpath = `.//div[@class='select-action']/i` or you specifically want to you css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `ActionsChains`. First you would have to import it using the line:

`from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains`

```
 time.sleep(8) --wait until invoice screen appears
 WebElement temp = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("i[class='ion-android-checkbox-outline-blank']"));
 action=ActionChains(driver)
 action.click(temp).preform(); --selecting checkbox
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Sil')]").click() --clicking on the sent button
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Evet')]").click() --approve to sent
 time.sleep(12) --wait till current invoices are sent and checkbox become re-eligible to select

 action.click(temp).preform();
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: sorry I'm a total newbie but it gives syntax error for temp. Adding the screenshot to the question.

Comment: What is the error exactly? And no need to apologize :)

Comment: I changed the `driver.find.Element...` line. try using what I just edited

Comment: manged to run but getting this one now:  "line 52, in <module>
    temp = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("i[class='ion-android-checkbox-outline-blank']"))
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'findElement'

Comment: Solved that issue by `temp = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//e-arsiv/taslaklar/div[4]/div[3]/div/div/i")` However, now getting **NameError: name 'Actions' is not defined**. Should I import a specific class?

Comment: Yes, you're missing the import. Also I should've noticed earlier but you're using python. So you would be using `ActionChains` instead of just `Action`. I've updated my answer, try it out now.

Comment: Thanks! It worked again for the first time but for the second `action.click(temp).perform()` giving *StaleElementReferenceException*. In order to solve that error ı tried this loop `retryingFindClick2(by):
        attempts=0
        while (attempts < 100):
                try:
                        action.click(by).perform()
                        result = True
                        break
                except StaleElementReferenceException:
                        attempts= attempts + 1
        return result` It soleve the error but again didn't perfom the checkbox clicking

Comment: Found the solution by refreshing the browser every time

Comment: great that you found the solution. If you found it while using my  answer, could you mark this as the the accepted answer so the question can be resolved and closed?

Answer (score 0):

Please wait until the checkbox element becomes clickable and then perform the click.

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    driver.element_to_be_clickable((By.xpath, "//button[contains(text(),'Sil')]"));
element.click
)
```

There is no other reason this can fail.