# The radio button is not getting selected with this HTML code for that. How to do that?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
<input id="radio2" name="radioGroup" type="radio">
<label class="flRight" for="radio2">
  ::before
  "Senior Citizen"
  ::after
</label>
```

```
WebElement senior = driver.findElement(By.id("radio2"));
      senior.click();
```

Now the problem is the code is not able to click the desired element.

Comment: Try using different ways of clicking an element. (Link)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y-other-elem  Second way always works for me.

Comment: You might need to post the full HTML, or a link, for the page you are trying to automate. Your locator strategy looks fine, and WebDriverWait does not solve the issue either. The most likely problem here is that your locator is not specific enough, and it is not  finding the correct element to click.

Answer (score 1):

Use WebDriverWait:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
WebElement senior = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("radio2")));
senior.click();
```

After seeing the WebSite it looks like the `input` is not the element you want to click rather the `label`...

So just change the `senior` var to:

```
WebElement senior = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='RadioButton']//label[@for='radio2']")));
```

The best way to automate human actions in the case where the element is not clickable dew to other elements covering them is to use `Actions`:

```
WebElement senior = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='RadioButton']//label[@for='radio2']")));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(senior).click().build().perform();
```

(using `JavascriptExecutor` and `executeScript` doesn't **realy** click... it just invokes the method that can be good but not for testing...)

As a last resort use `JavascriptExecutor`:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse= (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", senior);
```

Comment: No it's still not able to identify the element

Comment: It's not getting clicked... well the website is "https://www.axisbank.com/retail/calculators/fd-calculator" and I need to select the radio button next to Senior Citizen

Comment: How did you get the xpath of that?

Comment: I use the `inspect` button in Chrome... the `ctrl` + `f` and input any xpath that's an easy way to ensure your xpaths

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
WebElement senior = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='radioBtn']/label[2]"));
    WebElement close = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@id='nvpush_cross']"));
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(close));
    close.click();
    senior.click();
```

Code didnt worked before because there is popup you need to close it.

Comment: I have updated the xpath after going through the link that you have provided.

Comment: Still not able to click it.

Comment: FAILED: f
org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <label class="flRight" for="radio2">...</label> is not clickable at point (492, 602). Other element would receive the click: <div class="overLay" style="z-index: 99; display: block;"></div>

Comment: Still not getting clicked :(

Comment: nice catch with `"nvpush_cross"`

Comment: @MosheSlavin I ran it in my environment and saw there is pop up, probably that is what the problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to induce `WebdriverWait` And to click on the radio button use `JavaScript Executor` since neither `webdriver` click nor action class is working

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20); 
WebElement item=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//label[@class='flRight' and @for='radio2']")));
JavascriptExecutor js= (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below solution :

```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
  WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//label[@class='flRight' and @for='radio2']")));

  Actions action=new Actions(driver);
  action.moveToElement(element).click().perform();
```