# Getting "org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException" when invoking a CLICK using Selenium Java Test case

Tags: java, html, selenium, automated-tests, runtimeexception

I am using the below java code with Katalon Selenium IDE.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.By; 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

  public static void setUp() throws Exception {
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\myuser\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
 driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }


public static void testQScan() throws Exception {
    driver.get("https://qualysguard.myorg.com/fo/login.php?idm_key=saml2_78743hhh43");
    WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='userNameInput']")));
    System.out.println("Title of the page is 8 -> " + driver.getTitle());
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Scans")).click();
    System.out.println("Title of the page is 9 -> " + driver.getTitle());
}
```

After launching the base URL it is supposed to click on the "Scans" TAB. 
This works fine and the "Scans" TAB gets clicked when played using Selenium/Katalon browser plugin IDE.

However, running the exported java code gives me the following error:

Output:

```
Title of the page is 8 -> Dashboard
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <a onclick="javascript: showProcessing('...');" href="/fo/tools/module_landing.php?module=prod_scans" class="module-link">Scans</a> is not clickable at point (180, 100). Other element would receive the click: <div id="page-loading-mask" style="visibility: visible;">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.75)
Build info: version: '3.141.0', revision: '2ecb7d9a', time: '2018-10-31T20:09:30'
System info: host: 'AB-MYHOST7', ip: '10.9.9.112', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 77.0.3865.75, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 77.0.3865.40 (f484704e052e0..., userDataDir: C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Loc...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:51849}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 71b1daf7a06f6215547e7c79485c295e
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:285)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)
at pack.QScan.testQualysScan(QScan.java:139)
at pack.QScan.main(QScan.java:212)
```

Please provide suggestions on how I can overcome the error.

View Source on the browser for Scans Tab has the below entry:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="top_modules_bar">
  <div class="module-tabs-tab module-tabs-tab-selected">
    <a onclick="javascript: showProcessing('Dashboard');" href="/fo/compliance/index.php?skip=1" class="module-link">Dashboard</a>
  </div>
  <div class="module-tabs-tab">
    <a onclick="javascript: showProcessing('Policies');" href="/fo/tools/module_landing.php?module=prod_policies" class="module-link">Policies</a>
  </div>
  <div class="module-tabs-tab">
    <a onclick="javascript: showProcessing('Scans');" href="/fo/tools/module_landing.php?module=prod_scans" class="module-link">Scans</a>
  </div>
  <div class="module-tabs-tab">
    <a onclick="javascript: showProcessing('Reports');" href="/fo/tools/module_landing.php?module=prod_reports" class="module-link">Reports</a>
  </div>
  <div class="module-tabs-tab">
    <a onclick="javascript: showProcessing('Exceptions');" href="/fo/tools/module_landing.php?module=prod_exceptions" class="module-link">Exceptions</a>
  </div>
  <div class="module-tabs-tab">
    <a onclick="javascript: showProcessing('Assets');" href="/fo/tools/module_landing.php?module=prod_assets" class="module-link">Assets</a>
  </div>
  <div class="module-tabs-tab">
    <a onclick="javascript: showProcessing('Users');" href="/fo/tools/module_landing.php?module=prod_users" class="module-link">Users</a>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y-other-elem) is a very complete answer in another question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Actions class or javascript executer:

```
Actions act =  new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.linkText("Scans"))).click().perform();
```

OR

```
try {
     driver.findElement(By.linkText("Scans")).click();
  } catch (Exception e) {
     JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
     executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.linkText("Scans")));
  }
```

Comment: When you use JS on the page, you are shortcutting around the UI. In this specific case, you can't click the link because the click is intercepted. If you read the exception message it states exactly why... there is a loading dialog up. If you click the element using JS, the page may not be completely loaded which may cause issues immediately or later. This is dangerous and should not be done unless you fully understand the scenario and what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

To click on Scans Induce `WebDriverWait` and `elementToBeClickable()` and following `Xpath` option

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='module-tabs-tab']//a[text()='Scans']"))).click();
```

Or use actions class to click.

```
WebElement scanEle =new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='module-tabs-tab']//a[text()='Scans']")));
Actions action =new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(scanEle).click().build().perform();
```