# Selenium and Python. Element not clickable at point (x,y) because another element obscures it

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am attempting to select a checkbox on a webpage using Selenium and Python using this line of code

```
self.driver.find_element_by_id('lg_1166').click()
```

but am getting this error message

```
Message: Element <input id="lg_1699" name="lg_1699" type="checkbox"> is not clickable at point (284,888) because another element <div class="col-12 text-center"> obscures it
```

Then, when I inspect that same webpage looking for `<div class="col-12 text-center">`, there is no matching HTML.

[Here's the HTML of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyKY1.png)

I am unfamiliar with `waits` in Selenium and was wondering if anyone could help me resolve this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Add html code of the page

Comment: Add the website link please.

Comment: Please don't use images for code and provide relevant code blocks to show us what you have attempted to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium Web Driver & Java. Element is not clickable at point (x, y). Other element would receive the click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y-other-elem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite common in HTML for some elements to be visually placed over others in the UI rendering. When Selenium `WebElement.click()` is used, the visual dimension of the element on which click has to be performed is obtained and click is performed. If there is an element occupying the same visual space, error is thrown.

There are 2 possible solutions.

1. You can wait until the element is clickable using the below explicit wait

   ```
   element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'lg_1166')))
   element.click();
   ```
2. Use javascript executor to click on the element. This would trigger a javascript click on the element by-passing the visual click.

   ```
   element = driver.find_element_by_id('lg_1166')
   driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
   ```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so so much!